# c++ error C3200

Tags: c++, templates

I'm struggling with compile error C3200

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3xwxftta.aspx discusses the problem and gives as an example:

```
// C3200.cpp
template<typename T>
class X
{
};

template<template<typename U> class T1, typename T2>
class Y
{
};

int main()
{
   Y<int, int> y;   // C3200
}
```

and suggests that instead

```
Y<X, int> y;
```

must be used. but i don't really understand this... why can't it be

```
Y<X<int>, int> y;
```

? that would make more sense for me because in the suggested way the actual type of y is still not really defined.. if i extend the given example with some variables i get this:

```
// C3200.cpp
template<typename T>
class X
{
    char someChar;
    T someOtherVar;
};

template<template<typename U> class T1, typename T2>
class Y
{
    T1 var1;
    T2 var2;
};
```

so if i just specify 
    Y y; 
as in the suggested solution, the compiler still does not know how many bytes to reserve for y - no?

can someone explain me what's going on?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
template<template<typename U> class T1, typename T2>
```

Here `T1` is a so-called "[template template parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213761/what-are-some-uses-of-template-template-parameters-in-c)". It means it should accept a template. `X` is a template, `X<int>` is instantiated to a class.

```
template<template<typename U> class T1, typename T2>
class Y
{
    T1 var1;
    T2 var2;
};
```

This does not compiles because T1 is a template, not a type. To make T1 a type, you need to pass a parameter to it e.g.

```
template<template<typename U> class T1, typename T2>
class Y
{
    T1<T2> var1;
    T2 var2;
};
```

Comment: good explanation! i understood template template parameters wrong. now it's clear, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

C3200 complains that the first "int" in "Y<int, int>" can not be forced to match "template<typename U> class T1" because that int is not a template type.  That is the only issue that C3200 is raising.  However, "X<int>" would also be wrong because that would be a nontemplate type.  The first parameter has to be a templated type, not a "fully resolved" type.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding of the issue is that the first template type of `Y` should be a templated type in and of itself. `X` would be a templated type whereas `X<int>` is an instantiation of that type and doesn't meet the criteria for `Y`'s first template parameter.