# How take param of the template template class

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming, c++11

I have a type like `Type<Param>`. How I can retrieve the Param in c++11?

May be something like that:

```cpp
// I know it's not correct but it conveys the idea very well
template
<
   template <class Param> class Type 
>
struct GetParam
{
   typedef Param Result;
};

// e.g.
typedef GetParam<std::vector<double>>::Result X; // must return double
typedef GetParam<std::list<double>>::Result X; // double
typedef GetParam<std::vector<std::list<double>>::Result X; // std::list<double>
```

Comment: Perhaps have a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/q/213811/296460

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
template<class Type>
struct GetParam;

template<template<typename ...> class Tmp, typename T1, typename ...Types>
struct GetParam<Tmp<T1, Types...>> {
  typedef T1 type;
};
```

However the class template specialization you pass to `GetParam` can only have type template arguments. So you cannot pass `std::array` for example. It is not possible to do a fully generic `GetParam`, because you would have to enlist every possible template parameter list variety, and there are basically infinitely many.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like tr2 might have a typelist in type traits.
With g++-4.7 you can write this:

```
template<class Type>
  struct GetParam2;

template<template<typename ...> class Tmpl, typename Type, typename ...Types>
  struct GetParam2<Tmpl<Type, Types...>>
  {
    typedef typename std::tr2::typelist<Type, Types...> tlist;
    typedef typename tlist::first::type type;
    typedef typename tlist::rest::type types;
  };

typedef GetParam2<std::vector<double>>::type dbl2; // double
static_assert(std::is_same<dbl, dbl2>::value, "Ouch");
typedef GetParam2<std::list<double>>::type dbl2; // double
typedef GetParam2<std::vector<std::list<double>>>::type listdbl2; // std::list<double>
static_assert(std::is_same<listdbl, listdbl2>::value, "Ouch");
typedef GetParam2<std::array<double, 3>>::type arrdbl; // std::list<double>
```

Everything works but the last line with array.  Maybe I'm using it wrong.

It's about the same as johannes-schaub-litb answer but it'll be nice to have the library support.