# QuickCheck-Like Template Function Benchmarking in C++

Tags: c++, templates, testing, functional-programming, benchmarking

Inspired by Haskell's elegant way of auto-generating (random) instances of a given type, for example in QuickCheck, I'm trying to figure out how to write an *as-easy-to-use-as-possible* benchmarking framework in C++. I figure I will be using function templates, possibly with the help of new features in C++11 such as variadic templates. My hope is that I only need to specify a function or even better a function template and an STL template container type (an in turn its `value_type`) compatible with the argument(s) of the function.

I figured, that benchmarking a function with a set of inputs of various size is somewhat similar to how threads are setup and spawned in C++11. My first try would be to copy the constructor of the `thread` class and turn it into a `benchmark` function as

```
template< class Function, class ...Args >
inline
void benchmark( Function&& f, Args&&... args );
```

I'm not sure whether we should use r-value refs here or not. However `f` and `args` must be explicitly instantiated prior to the call to `benchmark` resulting in cumbersome *non-functional* use.

This lead to me to try to skip call arguments and only use template arguments instead:

```
namespace pnw
{
    template <template <typename> class Function, typename Container>
    inline
    void benchmark_container()
    {
        Function<typename Container::iterator> f;
        Container c(10);
        f(c.begin(), c.end());
    }
}
```

called as

```
typedef int T;
typedef std::vector<T> C;
pnw::benchmark_container<std::sort, C>();
```

However, compilation now errors as

```
tests/t_histogram.cpp: In function ‘void test_benchmark()’:
tests/t_histogram.cpp:56:44: error: no matching function for call to ‘benchmark_container()’
tests/t_histogram.cpp:56:44: note: candidate is:
tests/../benchmark.hpp:32:6: note: template<template<class> class Function, class Container> void pnw::benchmark_container()
```

I'm not sure whether C++ can handle transferring function template solely over the template arguments of another calling function.

Is this the right way to do it or is this not possible in C++11? I'm using GCC-4.6.

Comment: QuickCheck is a unit testing library, not a benchmarking library...

Comment: If you're interested in other solutions, check out my [QuickCheck clone for C++11](https://github.com/thejohnfreeman/autocheck).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to support "higher-kinded" parameters, you have to use [template-template parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213761/what-are-some-uses-of-template-template-parameters-in-c). Also, inside a template, `f::g` will be considered a value if not qualified by `typename`. Therefore you should write:

```
template <template <typename> class Function, typename Container>  // <--
inline void benchmark_container()
{
    Function<typename Container::iterator> f;   // <--
    ...
```

(All of these are available before C++11.)

---

**Edit:** But the call

```
benchmark_container<std::sort, C>();
```

won't work, because `std::sort` is an overloaded template function, not a class template. You cannot refer to `std::sort` alone either, because it would be ambiguous.

If you only want to work with functions like `std::sort` which has no associated contexts, you could pass a function pointer to disambiguate with overload to use:

```
template <typename Container,
          void (*func)(typename Container::iterator, typename Container::iterator)>
inline void benchmark_container()
{
    Container c (10);
    func(c.begin(), c.end());
}

benchmark_container<std::vector<int>, std::sort>();
```

or

```
template <typename Container>
inline void benchmark_container(void (*func)(typename Container::iterator, typename Container::iterator))
{
    Container c (10);
    func(c.begin(), c.end());
}

benchmark_container<std::vector<int>>(std::sort);
```

or just manually choose which overload you'd like to use, allowing general function objects to be passed:

```
template <typename Container, typename F>
inline void benchmark_container(const F& function)
{
    Container c (10);
    function(c.begin(), c.end());
}

benchmark_container<std::vector<int>>(std::sort<std::vector<int>::iterator>);
```

Comment: Thanks. I still get an error though: 

`tests/t_histogram.cpp:56:44: error: no matching function for call to ‘benchmark_container()’
tests/t_histogram.cpp:56:44: note: candidate is:
tests/../benchmark.hpp:32:6: note: template<template<class> class Function, class Container> void pnw::benchmark_container()`

I'm calling it as

`typedef int T;
typedef std::vector<T> C;
pnw::benchmark_container<std::sort, C>();`

Comment: Superb answer. If I had more stars I would give them to you ;)