# Pass template typename with free template argument

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

In C++11 (or C++) is it possible to pass a template type that is not fully specified. Specifically, I want to pass a type that does not have all of its template specifiers defined yet:

```
template <std::size_t N, typename ARRAYTYPE>
struct A {
  ARRAYTYPE<int, N> int_array;
};

int main() {
  A<10, std::array> my_a;
  return 0;
}
```

I know that simply redefining `ARRAYTYPE = std::array<int, 10>` would work, but would not let me utilize an `ARRAYTYPE` of different size anywhere in `A`:

```
template <std::size_t N, typename ARRAYTYPE>
struct A {
  ARRAYTYPE<int, N> int_array;
  ARRAYTYPE<int, 1> tiny_int_array;
};
```

**Is this possible?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's called a "template template parameter", because it's a template parameter whose value is a template:

```
template <std::size_t N, template <typename, std::size_t> class ARRAYTYPE>
struct A {
  ARRAYTYPE<int, N> int_array;
  ARRAYTYPE<int, 1> tiny_int_array;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

That would not be a type, but a template:

```
template <std::size_t N, template <typename, std::size_t> class ARRAY_TMPL>
struct A {
   ARRAY_TMPL<int, N> int_array;
};
```

Comment: I think that needs to be `<typename, std::size_t>`, otherwise e.g. `std::array` and `boost::array` wouldn't work.

Comment: @ildjarn: Yes, missed that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're trying to accomplish, you can pass the template itself as a [template template parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213761/what-are-some-uses-of-template-template-parameters-in-c).

Comment: That would be great! Can you explain?