# How to make tree structure with custom selection of underlying container?

Tags: c++, templates

I try to make a templated Trie structure. It represents tree in internal private struct `Node`, which contains `TElem`, `bool` which indicates that this particular node is a terminal and a vector of children:

```
template<typename TElem>
class Trie
{
    // ...
private:
    struct Node
    {
        TElem elem;
        bool isTerminal;
        std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Node>> children;
    };

    Node root_;
};
```

Now I'd like to make another template parameter that would make possible to select another underling container, e.g. `list`. How can it be done?

Comment: template template parameters http://stackoverflow.com/questions/213761/what-are-some-uses-of-template-template-parameters-in-c.

Comment: See my last edit. It allows to chose an allocator class template without exposing `Node`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With template template parameters (untested code, but the general idea should be OK):

```
template <typename TElem, 
          template <typename, typename> class Cont
          template <typename> class Allocator=std::allocator>
class Trie {
 private:
    struct Node
    {
        typedef std::shared_ptr<Node> NodePtr_;
        TElem elem;
        bool isTerminal;
        Cont<NodePtr_, Allocator<NodePtr_>> children;
    };

    Node root_;
};
```

then

```
Trie<int, std::list> myTrie = ....;
```

Comment: Tahnk you, after some improvements (you forgot second template parameter `Allocator`) everything works fine. :)

Comment: @Archie and I guess one would need a nested template template parameter for the allocator too (unless you can keep that fixed to `std::allocator<Whatever>`.

Comment: @Archie well, it took me a while to remind myself how to do this!