# what does (template) rebind<> do?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, stl

trying to learn more about how the standard library is actually implemented I'm inspecting all containers in visual studio.. Here I see some curious structure:

In some base class of a `std::list<>` The following typedef is found

```
typedef typename _Alloc::template rebind<_Ty>::other _Alty;
```

Where "_Alloc" corresponds with the allocator template argument (and _Ty the contained type). I have trouble finding a good explanation of this "keyword". Best thing I've found so far is that it is part of the allocator interface. Though even [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Allocator) isn't very good in explaining this.

What does this `template rebind<>` do? And why is it necessary at that location?

Comment: Related, see [Why is allocator::rebind necessary when we have template template parameters?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12362363)

Answer (score 51, accepted):

The `_Alloc` template is used to obtain objects of some type. The container may have an internal need to allocate objects of a different type. For example, when you have a `std::list<T, A>`, the allocator `A` is meant to allocate objects of type `T` but the `std::list<T, A>` actually needs to allocate objects of some node type. Calling the node type `_Ty`, the `std::list<T, A>` needs to get hold of an allocator for `_Ty` objects which is using the allocation mechanism provided by `A`. Using

```
typename _A::template rebind<_Ty>::other
```

specifies the corresponding type. Now, there are a few syntactic annoyances in this declaration:

1. Since `rebind` is a member template of `_A` and `_A` is a template argument, the `rebind` becomes a dependent name. To indicate that a dependent name is a template, it needs to be prefixed by `template`. Without the `template` keyword the `<` would be considered to be the less-than operator.
2. The name `other` also depends on a template argument, i.e., it is also a dependent name. To indicate that a dependent name is a type, the `typename` keyword is needed.

Comment: Wait, but that would mean that (when the list is `std::list<T, A>`); `rebind<T>` becomes redundant? as it would convert "T" to "T" type?

Comment: @paul23: If `_Ty` is the template argument, rather than something like `typedef _Node<_T> _Ty`, could be useful to make sure that the allocator creates the appropriate types. Although I'm pretty sure that `A` in `std::list<T, A>` needs to be able to deal with `T` objects, an allocator of a different may be passed in. I'm not sure about the standard requirements. It may be an extension to support allocators for different types.

Comment: List of T allocates nodes containing T as a member.  So the T allocator is useless to it directly.  Instead it makes a new one.  Your comment does not make sense to me @paul23

Comment: @Yakk: I think the allocator for type `T` is used to pull out some types defined in the containers, e.g., `std::list<T, A>::reference`. However, it seems that `std::list<int, std::allocator<long> >` compiles. If the allocator isn't rebound, the `reference` type in the above list would be `long&` rather than `int&`.

Comment: The standard requires (in Table 99) that `A::value_type` is the same type as `std::list<T,A>::value_type` i.e. is the same type as `T`, so it's undefined to instantiate e.g. `std::list<int, std::allocator<long>>` ... but at least libstdc++ (and maybe other impls) allow it as an extension and rebind the allocator internally. I can't remember why they allow it though!

Comment: Also `reference` is a bad example ... in C++11 allocators don't need to define `reference` or `const_reference` and even if they do provide them containers are not allowed to use the allocator's typedefs. The point is valid regarding the `pointer` type and `long*` and `int*` though.

Comment: I came across this question when I was learning about allocators. I would just like to mention for future readers like me that it is better practice to use [allocator_traits](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator_traits) when working with allocators. Especially in C++17 and newer where many members of [allocator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator) are getting deprecated/removed.  
Here is a simple linked list that uses rebind through `std::allocator_traits`:
https://godbolt.org/z/c4WK3Y

Answer (score 10):

`rebind` is for allocating memory for a type that differs from the element type of the container being implemented.  Take from [this MSDN article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/standard-library/allocator-class?view=msvc-170#remarks-12):

> For example, given an allocator object al of type A, you can allocate an object of type _Other with the expression:
>
> ```cpp
> A::rebind<Other>::other(al).allocate(1, (Other *)0)
> ```
>
> Or, you can name its pointer type by writing the type:
>
> ```cpp
> A::rebind<Other>::other::pointer
> ```

Answer (score 6):

Example in the code of stdc++ : /usr/include/4.8/ext/new_allocator.h

rebind is defined as a structure member of the allocator class; this structure defines a member **other** that is defined as an instance of the allocator specialized for a different argument type (the **other** member defines an allocator class that can creates a different type of objects)

```
 template<typename _Tp>
    class new_allocator
    {
    public:
      ...
      template<typename _Tp1>
        struct rebind
        { typedef new_allocator<_Tp1> other; };
```

When it is used:

```
  typedef typename _Alloc::template rebind<_Tp>::other _Tp_alloc_type;
```

the type of the allocator is referenced as

```
  typename _Alloc::template rebind<_Tp>::other
```

Now the typedef is used to define **_Tp_alloc_type** - which can then be used as a shorter name for the same thing.

An example usage is in std::list where the internal list node also needs its allocator, which is redefined from the argument allocator.

Answer (score -1):

please check this http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/allocator/

you will see

rebind<...> is actually a member of class allocator which is part of STL without giving source code of the implementation.

as you see, rebind<...> is also a template and it deserve a type to let the allocator class knows what is in my rebind member.

so back to your statement:
typedef typename _Alloc::template rebind<_Ty>::other _Alty;
if you omitted the template:
typedef typename _Alloc::rebind<_Ty>::other _Alty; 
you can easy understand that rebind is member of _Alloc, but compiler can NOT understand.

Given the nature of rebind being the template, template rebind<_Ty> is needed and is treated 
as the whole not two parts.