# GCC stl_tree.h red-black tree source code for std::set

Tags: c++, gcc, set, std, red-black-tree

I am looking at the following GCC source code file stl_tree.h:

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/libstdc++-html-USERS-4.1/stl__tree_8h-source.html

and in particular, this part:

```
struct _Rb_tree_impl : public _Node_allocator
        {
      _Key_compare      _M_key_compare;
      _Rb_tree_node_base    _M_header;
      size_type         _M_node_count; // Keeps track of size of tree.
```

I am trying to work out what data members a `_Rb_tree_impl` object has- by this I mean the data members it may inherit from `_Node_allocator`.

On line 330 it defines `_Node_allocator` as:

```
typedef typename _Alloc::template rebind<_Rb_tree_node<_Val> >::other _Node_allocator;
```

I do not know how to find the definition for this type to check what data members it contains. Could someone please help? Where is this class/struct located?

Comment: This SO answer may be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14148870/12711

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The allocator is stateless, so it doesn't contain any fields. The purpose of the `impl` class is to not cost you any space for the allocator by employing base class layout optimizations.

The naive implementation would waste space:

```
template <typename T, typename Alloc>
class NaiveContainer
{
    Node<T*> root;     // just for exposition
    Alloc alloc;

public:
    NaiveContainer(Alloc const & a = Alloc()) : alloc(a) {}
    Alloc get_alloc() const { return alloc; }
    // ...
};
```

This class is strictly larger than it needs to be. So the cleverer solution is with a private nested class:

```
template <typename T, typename Alloc>
class EboContainer
{
    struct Impl : Alloc
    {
        Impl(Alloc const & a) : Alloc(a) {}
        Node<T*> root;
    };
    Impl impl;

public:
    EboContainer(Alloc const & a = Alloc) : impl(a) {}
    Alloc get_alloc() const { return impl;  /* slicing */ }
    // ...
};
```

Now the class is exactly as large as it needs to be to hold the relevant data members. Incidentally, this implementation is an example of when slicing is useful.

Comment: Ok I get what you are saying- I don't understand how the code achieves this though? "base class layout optimizations"

Comment: @mezamorphic: the size of a base subobject is allowed to be less than the size of a complete object of the same type.

Comment: and what part of the sub object is "removed"/sliced to achieve this?

Comment: *The allocator is stateless* is quite an overstatement, the allocator **may** be stateless (or not). Also, in the implementation the OP mentions, the type is not a *nested* type, although it does not matter much for the answer.

Comment: @mezamorphic: I think the relevant base class layout optimization is the possibility that a base class not occupy any space. From [intro.object]/5: "Unless it is a bit-field (9.6), a most derived object shall have a non-zero size and shall occupy one or more
bytes of storage. Base class subobjects may have zero size."

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: I believe that `std::allocator` is always stateless, non?

Comment: @KerrekSB: `std::allocator` is stateless (well, in most implementations). The the containers in the standard library must support stateful allocators since C++11. C++03 had some weirdness where the combination of requirements ended up implying that allocators could not have state, but that changed in C++11. Don't get me wrong, the answer is correct: the allocator is moved to a base because the most frequent allocator is stateless and you can take advantage of EBO.