# A query regarding allocator rebind

Tags: c++, c++11, allocator

Under [C++ concepts: Allocator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Allocator#Allocator_completeness_requirements)

would like some clarity on the following:

> A::template rebind::other (optional[1](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Allocator#Allocator_completeness_requirements))
>
> Notes: [1](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Allocator#Allocator_completeness_requirements) rebind is only optional (provided by `std::allocator_traits`)
>   if this allocator is a template of the form `SomeAllocator<T, Args>`,
>   where `Args` is zero or more additional template parameters.

Why would `rebind` be optional in the above case?

Comment: It is "generated" in that case (to be `SomeAllocator<U, Args>`).

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14148756/what-does-template-rebind-do and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12362363/why-is-allocatorrebind-necessary-when-we-have-template-template-parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard library always accesses Allocators through the `std::allocator_traits` template. This template provides a default definition of `rebind` if it conforms to the form `Alloc<U, Args>`

> `rebind_alloc<T>` `Alloc::rebind<T>::other` if present, otherwise `Alloc<T, Args>` if this `Alloc` is `Alloc<U, Args>` - [cppreference.com : std::allocator_traits](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator_traits)