# How does boost::allocate_shared store passed allocator?

Tags: c++, boost, shared-ptr

I know it accepts a reference to the allocator, but then what? Does it create a copy of it or keep storing it as a reference? I couldn't find that out with a debugger.

Comment: Just check the [documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/smart_ptr/make_shared.html#functions): `allocate_shared` uses **a copy of `a`** to allocate memory. I believe the constant reference parameter itself cannot be used, since `allocate` can be a non-const member function.

Comment: @DanielLangr I've checked the new version of [documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/libs/smart_ptr/doc/html/smart_ptr.html#make_shared) and it says: "Uses a **rebound** copy of a". What does that mean?

Comment: See, e.g., [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14148756/580083), where you find explanations what allocator-rebinding means. Basically, it just instantiates an allocator from the same allocator class template but with different value type (its template argument).