# Why is there a :: template after a c++ class name?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, variadic-templates

In some base class of a `std::list<>` The following typedef is found

```
typedef typename _Alloc::template rebind<_Ty>::other _Alty;
```

I am having hard time breaking the above declaration to understand. How to read the above easily and

1. Why is there a `::` template after `_Alloc`?
2. What is `std::rebind`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [what does (template) rebind<> do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14148756/what-does-template-rebind-do)

Comment: @BKN - I went through that but didn't get much clarity to break down the declaration and understand. Hence posted the above question.

Comment: In this context, `_Alloc` is a template type parameter, so the compiler doesn't know what `_Alloc::rebind` is yet. The word `template` is there to tell the compiler that `rebind` should be interpreted as a template. Without it, the compiler will think that the `<` is a less-than operator rather than a template parameter marker.

Comment: @Test You deleted the other question, you were \*this* close to getting the solution you wanted. I posted it https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240991/rotating-boost-polygon with an explanation. Please undelete the post so other people can benefit from that too?

Comment: @sehe - how do I see the questions I deleted? I am unable to locate the same.

Comment: @Test I think you can click the "Recently deleted" link at the bottom of [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16224437/Test?tab=questions). Likely this link should work for you when logged in: https://stackoverflow.com/users/recently-deleted-questions/16224437

Comment: @sehe - I have enabled back that question. thanks