# What type is used by std::allocate_shared to allocate memory?

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr, dynamic-memory-allocation, allocator

From https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/allocate_shared:

> ```cpp
> template< class T, class Alloc, class... Args >
> shared_ptr<T> allocate_shared( const Alloc& alloc, Args&&... args );
> ```
>
> The storage is typically larger than `sizeof(T)` in order to use one allocation for both the control block of the shared pointer and the `T` object. ... All memory allocation is done using a copy of `alloc`, which must satisfy the [Allocator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Allocator) requirements.

What type is then used to allocate the aforementioned storage? In other words, what should be `Alloc::value_type`, one of the Allocator requirements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The actual type used depends on the implementation. By [*Allocator*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Allocator) requirements and with the help of [`std::allocator_traits`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator_traits) traits class template, any allocator can be `rebind`ed to another type via `std::allocator_traits<A>::rebind_alloc<T>` mechanism.

Suppose you have an allocator

```
template<class T>
class MyAlloc { ... };
```

If you write:

```
std::allocate_shared<T>(MyAlloc<T>{});
```

it doesn't mean that `MyAlloc<T>` will be used to perform allocations. If internally we need to allocate an object of another type `S`, we can get an appropriate allocator via

```
std::allocator_traits<MyAlloc<T>>::rebind_alloc<S>
```

It is defined such that if `MyAlloc` itself doesn't provide `rebind<U>::other` member type alias, the default implementation is used, which returns `MyAlloc<S>`. An allocator object is constructed from that passed to `std::allocate_shared()` (here, `MyAlloc<T>{}`) by an appropriate `MyAlloc<S>`'s converting constuctor (see *Allocator* requirements).

Let's take a look at some particular [implementation](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/shared_ptr_base.h) - libstdc++. For the line above, the actual allocation is performed by

```
MyAlloc<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<T, Alloc<T>, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>
```

which is reasonable: `std::allocate_shared()` allocates memory for an object that contains both `T` and a control block. `_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<T, ...>` is such an object. It holds `T` inside itself in the `_M_storage` data member:

```
__gnu_cxx::__aligned_buffer<T> _M_storage;
```

The same mechanism is used in many other places. For example, `std::list<T, Alloc>` employs it to obtain an allocator that is then used to allocate list nodes, which in addition to `T` hold pointers to their neighbours.

An interesting related question is why allocator is not a template template parameter, which might seem a natural choice. It is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25572251/in-allocator-aware-stl-classes-why-are-the-allocators-not-template-template-arg).

Comment: Thanks to your answer I was able to rewrite my little project to use `allocate_shared` together with a [specialized allocator](https://github.com/ppetr/refcounted-var-sized-class/blob/38311606201a6405352f63086255a0c8ed8778f5/var_sized.h#L33), thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't matter. The type must only satisfy the allocator requirements ([[util.smartptr.shared.create]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/util.smartptr.shared.create#2), also in C++11).

One of the requirements is that for every (cv-unqualified) object type `U`, `Alloc::rebind<U>::other` yields the corresponding allocator type for a `value_type` of `U` (or if this is not implemented directly in the allocator type that `allocator_­traits` can provide a default implementation by replacing the (first) template argument of the class template that `Alloc` is a specialization of.)

In this way, no matter for what `value_type` your passed allocator is, `std::allocate_shared` can just obtain an allocator to the (unspecified) type it requires for combined storage by rebinding.

For example, with

```
struct MyType {};

int main() {
    std::cout << "MyType size is " << sizeof(MyType) << "\n";
    allocator<MyType> a;
    auto x = std::allocate_shared<MyType>(a);
}
```

where `allocator` is a minimal allocator implementation printing details about every allocation call via `typeid`, I get for current GCC with libstdc++:

```
MyType size is 1
Allocating for 1 objects of type St23_Sp_counted_ptr_inplaceI6MyType9allocatorIS0_ELN9__gnu_cxx12_Lock_policyE2EE
    with size 24 each.
```

and with current Clang and libc++:

```
MyType size is 1
Allocating for 1 objects of type NSt3__120__shared_ptr_emplaceI6MyType9allocatorIS1_EEE
    with size 32 each.
```

https://godbolt.org/z/bPqeYTP7Y

Answer (score 0):

> what should be Alloc::value_type

The requirement of allocators is that `Alloc::value_type` is same as the `T` in the Allocator requirements - not to be confused with `T` of `allocate_shared`. So, for example, indirecting through `Alloc::​pointer` must yield a value of type `Alloc::value_type&`.

There is no requirement which `Alloc::value_type` needs to be for `std::allocate_shared` as long as it conforms to Allocator requirements.

> What type is used by std::allocate_shared to allocate memory?

`std::allocate_shared` will use a copy of `alloc` rebound to an unspecified `value_type`.