# What is meant by rebindable family types in C++?

Tags: c++, c++17

What does the term rebindable family types in C++ mean?

My query stems form the fact that allocators in c++ are supposed to be so-called rebindable family types.

And `std::allocator` has such a constructor:

```
template <typename U>
allocator(const allocator<U>& other);
```

alongwith

```
template<typename _Tp1>
        struct rebind
        { typedef new_allocator<_Tp1> other; };
```

Are there any custom examples to help understand that what is the need for this rebind to be there in first place within the std::allocator? What is the benefit it brings?

Comment: [Here are several answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14148756/what-does-template-rebind-do) Is there something in particular you would like to know?

Comment: Where did you get this term? It's the first time I hear it.

Comment: @lakeweb - The link you shared doesn't answer my query. I have also updated my question to get a clear picture

Comment: @Evg - I have added bit more context to the question.

Comment: @Test: I'm not sure what is missing from those answers. I couldn't explain it better than that first answer. What do you not understand?

Comment: The classic example is that `std::list<T, Alloc>` usually gets instantiated with `std::allocator<T>` - an allocator that can allocate instances of `T`. But that the list really needs to allocate is something like `struct Node {T data; Node* left; Node* right};` So it needs a way to obtain an allocator for `Node` from an allocator for `T` it's given. That's where `rebind` comes in.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik - Could you elaborate a bit more? How will rebind help in this case?

Comment: Something like `template <typename T, typename Alloc> std::list::list(const Alloc& alloc) {using NodeAlloc = typename Alloc::template rebind<Node>::other; NodeAlloc node_alloc(alloc); /* use node_alloc to allocate nodes */}`

Comment: A closely related [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70630632) I wrote a few days ago.