# Can I rebind the deleter type for unique_ptr?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, unique-ptr

Got some questions when using the `unique_ptr` and tried to read the source but more questions emerge.

The template parameter `Deleter` in `unique_ptr<class Tp, class Deleter = default_delete<Tp>>` is a class other than a template so I wonder if it uses some tricks like the `allocator::rebind` (discussion found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12362363)). But no, it must have an exact `operator()(pointer)` overload.

So I turned to the STL source (in Ubuntu 14.04 gcc 4.8) and find that a nested `_Pointer` class is defined for some type traits, but absolutely nothing to do with rebinding the `Deleter` type to something compatible with the pointer type.

```
// /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/unique_ptr.h:112
class _Pointer
{
    template<typename _Up>
    static typename _Up::pointer __test(typename _Up::pointer*);

    template<typename _Up>
    static _Tp* __test(...);

    // _Dp is the Deleter type
    typedef typename remove_reference<_Dp>::type _Del;
public:
    typedef decltype(__test<_Del>(0)) type;
};

// /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/unique_ptr.h:130
// adopt the pointer type provided by the _Pointer
typedef typename _Pointer::type   pointer;
```

I've no idea what that class is supposed to do but it seems the `Tp` parameter can be overrided. To test it I've fabricated some weird codes like this

```
struct MyDeleter {
    // in the deleter type, define the pointer as pointer to int
    typedef int* pointer;

    void operator()(pointer p)
    {
        delete p;
    }
};

int main()
{
    // this won't compile!
    std::unique_ptr<double, MyDeleter> p(new double(0));

    // this type is equivalent to std::unique_ptr<int, MyDeleter>
    std::unique_ptr<double, MyDeleter> p(new int(0));
    return 0;
}
```

I'm completely confused. Would anybody explain that

- Is there any approach to rebind the deleter type for `unique_ptr`?
- Why is there such a mechanism to override the pointer type? Is that stated in the standard or just a "feature" in the gcc implementation?

Answer (score 1):

The rules say that if `MyDeleter` has a nested type `pointer`, then that type is used. Otherwise `std::unique_ptr<double, MyDeleter>` will use `double*` formed from the first parameter.

And the pointer you store must match the resulting pointer type of the `unique_ptr`, otherwise the final delete would be UB.

So, in the first case of `std::unique_ptr<double, MyDeleter> p(new double(0));` you try to store a `double*` when the deleter expects an `int*`. That will never work, so it's good that the compiler catches it.