# Get the type from a pointer to std::array<T, N> using the [] operator?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, return

I have a class in my code that is comparable to `std::array<T1, N>` and a function :

```
template <class T2>
inline void f(T2* const myarray)
{
    std::pair<double, /*SOMETHING*/> x;
}
```

Assuming that `T2*` is a pointer to my class comparable to `std::array<T1, N>`, I would like to know what I have to write instead of `/*SOMETHING*/` to get `T1` from the `[]` operator of `myarray` ?

Note : I don't ask for a more clever way to get the type from a pointer to `std::array`.

Comment: It's possible you're looking for [*template template parameters*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/213761/what-are-some-uses-of-template-template-parameters-in-c).

Comment: `typename T2::value_type`?

Comment: If you're sure that it's a pointer to an array class/type, you can do `decltype((*myarray)[0])`

Comment: @SethCarnegie I forget, is that going to be a reference type? Might need to remove the reference.

Comment: @Pubby actually no, I just looked it up and it says that `decltype(...)` is the type, but `decltype((...))` is the reference.

Comment: so `typename std::remove_reference<decltype((*myarray)[0])>::type` is what I search for ?

Comment: @Vincent yes, though I'm not sure whether or not you need the `remove_reference` stuff.

Comment: @SethCarnegie I don't think so. `(*myarray)[0]` can only be treated as a expression, not as a declaration.

Comment: @Pubby yeah, I've no idea, I think I read the wiki article wrong.

Comment: @Vincent: Yes, use `typename std::remove_reference<decltype((*myarray)[0])>::type` or the much shorter `typename T2::value_type`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for me:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <array>
#include <utility>

template <class T2>
inline void f(T2* const myarray)
{
    std::pair<double, typename T2::value_type> x;
    static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(x.second), int>::value, "");
}

int
main()
{
    std::array<int, 2> a;
    f(&a);
}
```

If your "array-like" class template doesn't have a `value_type`, the following should also work:

```
std::pair<double, typename std::remove_reference<decltype((*myarray)[0])>::type> x;
```

But just fyi, const-qualified parameters are not generally used, and in C++11 will even be a pessimization if you happen to return the parameter (as in):

```
return myarray;
```

Though in this case `myarray` is a pointer and it doesn't really matter that it is const in this case.

If you instead meant:

```
inline void f(T2 const* myarray)
```

(pointer to a `const T2`, instead of a `const` pointer to a `T2`)

then the above recipe needs a slight adjustment:

```
std::pair<double, typename std::remove_const<
                                   typename std::remove_reference<
                                      decltype((*myarray)[0])
                                   >::type
                                >::type> x;
```

If your "array-like" class template does have `value_type`, then the first suggestion:

```
std::pair<double, typename T2::value_type> x;
```

works no matter where the `const` is.