# Template Conundrum

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, template-specialization

I have encountered a C++ template conundrum. I've tried to trim it down to the bare minimum, and now I'm not even sure if what I'm trying to do is possible. Take a look at the following code (in some .h file).

```
template<typename T>
class A
{
public:
    template<typename S>
    void f(S x);
};

class B1 { };

template<typename S>
class B2 { };

//This one works:
template<>
template<typename S>
void A<B1>::f(S x)
{
}    

//This one does not work:
template<>
template<typename S>
void A<B2<S>>::f(S x)
{
}
```

In my `main` function I have something like this:

```
//This one works:
A<B1> first;
first.f<int>(5);

//This one does not work:
A<B2<int>> second;
second.f<int>(5);
```

The error message I get because of the second part is

```
error C3860: template argument list following class
             template name must list parameters in the
             order used in template parameter list

error C3855: 'A<T>': template parameter 'T' is
             incompatible with the declaration
```

Any idea what the problem is?

---

## Edit

To make the problem more concrete, here's my motivation.  I want the function `f` above to have specializations for `T=std::tuple<T1, T2>`, `T=std::tuple<T1, T2, T3>`, and `T=std::tuple<T1, T2, T3, T4>`, where the types in the `tuple` are still unbound.

Comment: What are you trying to do with this? Maybe there is a better way.

Comment: Is this what you want? http://stacked-crooked.com/view?id=8b9365eab6441615b312ad76b0500bb7-18aa934a8d82d638dde2147aa94cac94

Comment: @Pubby I have added a section at the end with the motivation.

Comment: Re: your edit: That would be partial specialisation of a function template. Not possible. You could maybe emulate it by having the function delegate to a class template. Or how about plain overloads?

Comment: @TimothyShields just overload with `template<typename... T> void f(std::tuple<T...>);` then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to partially specialize a member function template. That is not possible, I'm afraid...

Answer (score 4):

Your code has two problems. First, the second specialization is illegal, because

```
template<> // parameters useable for the specialization of A you refer to
           // since it is a function, no partial specialization is allowed.
template<typename S> // parameters for the function's parameters
void A<B2<S>>          // S can not be used here!
             ::f(S x)  // only here
{
}
```

If I change that to

```
template<>
template<typename S>
void A<B2<int>>::f(S x)
{
}
```

it works and now the second problem is exposed:

```
second.f<B2<int>>(5);
```

This sets `S` to `B2<int>` and the function expect a parameter `S x` - but the integer `5` can not be converted to that type. Change it to:

```
B2<int> x;
second.f<B2<int>>(x);
```

and it works as well.

Note that this might not solve the problem you were trying to solve, it just explains what happens.

---

Thinking about your edit: I think the fact that you try to specialize for `T=std::tuple<...>` already points the direction: `T` is the template parameter of `A` and *that* is what you should specialize. Maybe something like:

```
template< typename T >
class F // used to implement f(), so you can specialize
        // just F/f() instead of the whole class A
{
  void f(T x) { /* default impl */ }
};

template< typename T1, typename T2 >
class F< std::tuple< T1, T2 > >
{
  void f(T1 x, T2 y) { /* special impl */ }
};

template< typename T >
class A : public F< T >
{
    // ...other stuff...
};
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pass another template to a template, you have to use [*template template parameters*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213761/what-are-some-uses-of-template-template-parameters-in-c), so your A<> template would look like this:

```
template<typename T>
class A
{
public:
    template<template <typename> class H, typename S>
    void f(H<S> x);
};
```

Now you can pass a template to your template.

I don't think you can specialize on template template parameters if your original template didn't take such an parameter type.

Comment: I'm looking into this now...will get back to you on whether it works for me. Looks promising.