# Alternatives to using template template parameters

Tags: c++, templates

I currently use a template class with multiple parameters,

```
template<class A, class B> class M{ };
```

However, in the position of class `A` I want to insert a template class, something like

```
template<class C> class A{ };
```

The only solution I've found for doing this is to use template template parameters:

```
template< template<class C> class A, class B> class M{ };
```

In my implementation, the only parameterization of `A` I use is `A<B>`. I don't need several instantiations of `A` using different parameters, for example I don't need to instantiate `A<int>` `A<double>` and `A<long double>` in `M`.

Is there an alternative to the template template parameter? The reason I ask is a follow up of this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213761/what-are-some-uses-of-template-template-parameters-in-c), in which in his answer @Evan Teran says he's only once ever had to use template template parameters...

I guess a twist on my question is: are there downsides to using template template parameters?

Comment: If you know the type beforehand, you can use it as an argument: `template <typename> struct foo` would accept `foo<std::vector<int>>`

Comment: If you only need one instantiation, don't take a template, but that concrete instantiation

Comment: For an alternative you can use wrapper class as a parameter: `struct A { template<class C> class type{...}; };`.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `B` can somehow be determined from `A<B>`, you can just take one template parameter:

```
template <class A> class M
{
  typedef typename A::The_B_Type B;
};
```

Of course, `The_B_Type` has to be a valid typedef within `A<B>`. That's one of the reasons why standard library containers provide all the typedefs. For example, if the template `A` was `std::vector`, you could do this:

```
template <class A> class M
{
  typedef typename A::value_type B;
};
```

Comment: @Yakk Of course \*smacks forehead\*. I think you should make that an answer.

Comment: I was going to be lazy and have you write it, but if you insist! :)

Comment: @Yakk I wouldn't want you to miss out on the rep. Have a +1 :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can take the instantiated `A<B>` as an argument, then use a traits class to extract the `B` passed to `A<B>` if you need it:

```
template<typename T>
struct extract_b {}; // SFINAE enabled
template<template<class>class A, typename B>
struct extract_b< A<B> > {
  typedef B type;
};

// C++11, you can replace it with typename extract_b<T>::type at point of use
// if you lack support for it:
template <typename T>
using ExtractB = typename extract_b<T>::type;

template<typename A>
struct M {
  typedef ExtractB<A> B;
  // ...
};
```

the traits class is poorly named, but you can see that I can get the `template` argument out of `A<B>` and expose it in `M<A>`.

Comment: Hmmm It seems to rely on me being able to instantiate `A` in advance. If an object of type `A` is a class member of `M`, does this mean I need to use a move/copy constructor?

Comment: @plamen instantiate the template amd get a type, not the instance.

Comment: I guess what I'm struggling with is this: how do I instantiate `M` with `A` a template member? This is why I thought template template parameter.

Comment: The problem is I'm not using primitive classes. I think this deserves a new question.