# Is there any use for named parameters into template template parameters

Tags: c++, templates, template-templates

If I need to define a template `foo` function with a template-template parameter, I usually do the following:

```
// Notice that the template parameter of class T is unnamed.
template <template <typename> class T> void f() { std::cout << "Yay!\n"; }
```

Notice that the template parameter of the template-template parameter is unnamed, but we can assign a name to this parameter:

```
// Now the template parameter of class T is named INNER.
template <template <typename INNER> class T> void f(const INNER &inner)
{ std::cout << inner << " Yay!\n"; }
```

This doesn't seems to be usefull at all, because I cannot reffer the `INNER` parameter in the function, the code above produces the following error:

> error: 'INNER' does not name a type

It surprises me that the `typename INNER` doesn't name a type, after all the `typename` keyword is there in order to naming a type. Anyway, this is easy to fix though:

```
// Now INNER is the name of the template parameter of class T and also
// the name of the second template parameter of foo.
template <template <typename INNER> class T, typename INNER> void f(const INNER &inner)
{ std::cout << inner << " Yay!\n"; }
// ...
f<std::valarray, int>(666); // Prints "666 Yay!"
```

But in the end, the `INNER` parameter doesn't need a name after all:

```
// Now the template parameter of class T is unnamed one more time,
// INNER is the name of the second template parameter of foo.
template <template <typename> class T, typename INNER> void f(const INNER &inner)
{ std::cout << inner << " Yay!\n"; }
// ...
f<std::valarray, int>(666); // Prints "666 Yay!"
```

And (sure you already noticed before me) the name in the parameter of the template-template parameter is ignored! It sure have been ignored because if not it should have a name-clash with the second template parameter of `foo`, doesn't it?

Another demonstration of the name of the parameter of the template-template parameter being ignored:

```
// Now T is the name of the template parameter of class T and also
// the name of the template parameter of foo!
template <template <typename T> class T> void f()
{ std::cout << "Yay!\n"; }
// ...
f<std::valarray>(); // prints "Yay!"
```

The type named `T` is being used by the template-template parameter and by the template-template itself at the same time? I don't think so, the name into the template-template parameter is ignored AFAIK.

So, what's the question?

1. Are my guess correct? The names of named template parameters of template-template parameters are ignored?
2. If I'm mistaken and I've misunderstood the whole thing, there's a use for the named parameters into the template-template parameters? Can you provide some useful examples?

As for *useful examples* on #2 i'm referring to something that only could be achieved using the named template parameters of template-template parameters.

Comment: I think reading through this QA: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/213761/what-are-some-uses-of-template-template-parameters-in-c will help guide why there wouldn't be any use in naming the template-template parameter. TTP's are essentially declaring the signature of a templated argument, not providing the templated method with additional template arguments. Similar to when you declare a functor, it's `(*foo)(type, type type)`, not `(*foo)(type name, type name, type name)`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[basic.scope.temp]/p1:

> The declarative region of the name of a template parameter of a
>   template *template-parameter* is the smallest *template-parameter-list*
>   in which the name was introduced.

<sub>(Now try saying that 10 times.)</sub>

It can be used inside that list. For instance,

```
template < template<class T, T t> class TP > class foo {};
//                           ^  ^-----T's scope ends here
//                           |
//                           T can be used here

foo<std::integral_constant> bar;
```

Comment: That's very similar to function declarations, by the way. The following illustrates the analogy by producing a compiler error: `void f(int x, decltype(x)); int main() { f(1, nullptr); }`. The following compiles and links fine: `void f(int x, decltype(x)); int main() { f(1, 1); } void f(int, int) {}
`. That's because the scope of `x` is just enough to encompass the `decltype` that comes after it.

Comment: Ok, so I was mistaken: the named parameter of template-template parameter isn't ignored, it simply doesn't exists outside its template-template class... the only use I can think of named template-template parameters is the following:

`template <template <typename T, typename = std::allocator<T>> class V> class f {};`