# Can a parameter of a template template parameter cause shadowing?

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, template-templates, shadowing

Is this legal C++?

```
template <typename T, template <typename T> class>
struct S { };
```

Clang (3.7.1) rejects it, complaining the second `T` shadows the first `T`.  GCC seems not to care about it and I think that's reasonable.  I think it is only the number of parameters that matters in a template template parameter.

- http://goo.gl/51bHVG (gcc.godbolt.org)

Comment: why do you need to use `T` twice? if you want to use `T` in the second template you can write `template <class T, template <class S=T> class>`

Comment: @DavidHaim It's not mandatory, but when the first parameter is supposed to be given to the second parameter which is a template template, it makes sense to use the same (or, at least a similar) name for the nested template parameter. Your suggestion is interesting, I've never tried to specify a default parameter to a template template parameter.  What does it accomplish compared to `template <class T, template <class S> class>` ?

Comment: I wonder what is the driving motivation for people who does search&destroy against tag words in a post title??  Are they perhaps equally enthusiastic in replacing `NULL` to `nullptr`?

Comment: Can be [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28992265/is-there-any-use-for-named-parameters-into-template-template-parameters) related?

Comment: @DavidHaim OK, with `template <template T, template <class S=T> class C>`, we can replace `C<T>` with `C<>` as if `C` was defined with a default template parameter... This _can_ be handy in some cases, but I'm not sure I'll be using it often. Anyways thanks so much.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster Thanks, they discuss when a parameter name of a template template parameter matters, and I was wrong in saying only the number of parameters would matter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. [[temp.local]/6](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.local#6):

> A *template-parameter* shall not be redeclared within its scope
>   (including nested scopes).

Comment: Hmm, it took me a while to realize your quote is actually relevant to my case, but right, it is surely about a "nested scope."

Answer (score 0):

While the right answer exists, it toke some time for myself to understand, and I **just wanted to add an example:**

```cpp
template <class Key, class T>
class MyData {
public:
    // ...

    template <class Key, class T>
    inline static MyData<Key, T> *get(MyMap<Key, T> *ptr)
    {
        return NULL: // Logic here...
    }

    // ...
}
```

As "`Template-parameters shall not be re-declared within its scope (including nested scopes)`",
above `get(..)` method should be changed and use other names, like:

```cpp
template <class KeyType, class Type>
inline static MyData<KeyType, Type> *get(MyMap<KeyType, Type> *ptr)
{
    return NULL: // Logic here...
}
```