# Template template parameters used as default value for other arguments

Tags: c++, templates

I'm trying to use a template template parameter as a default value for other template parameters but when I try to use the identifier (template template parameter name/id ) it cannot be found.
I'm using VS 2013.
The idea is that I have a "factory" class based on a specific type of template instantiation I need to return another object with the same number of parameters (4) BUT with the same specialization.

```
template<class T1, class T2,class T3, class T4>
class CommandBus
{...}

template <
template<class T1, class T2, class T3, class T4> class ListenerType,
//The Line bellow fails to compile, T1 is not visible
//E0020 identifier "T1" is undefine 
class CommandBusType = CommandBus<T1, T2, T3, T4> >
class CommandBusFactory {
static auto Get() {
        return CommandBusType{};
    }
};

int main{
//Say I would Have some Object :
Listener<int, int ,int int> Listener;
//Withought the Factory I would have to manually generate a ComamndBus of the same specialization (int , int , int, int):
CommandBus<int,int,int,int> cmdBus;


//But I could use a factory, things should look like:
Listener<int, int ,int int> listener;
auto cmdBus = CommandBusFactory<Listener<int,int,int,int>>::Get();
}
```

*I was expecting this to work but the compiler complains that for example 
identifier T1,T2 etc not found for the default value (CommandBus)for template parameter CommandBusType*.

**Is is possible to use template template arguments as default value for other template arguments?**

Comment: Short answer to the question in bold seems to be no: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28992265/is-there-any-use-for-named-parameters-into-template-template-parameters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first template paramater of `CommandBusFactory` is itself a template.

And yet, in `main` you pass `Listener<int,int,int,int>` to it, **which is not a template, but a type**. You need a type template parameter instead.

Then, to extract template arguments from that type you could use template specialization:

```
template
<
    class X,
    template <class, class, class, class> class Y
>
struct copy_template_params;

template
<
    template <class, class, class, class> class X,
    class A, class B, class C, class D,
    template <class, class, class, class> class Y
>
struct copy_template_params<X<A,B,C,D>,Y>
{
    using type = Y<A,B,C,D>;
};

template
<
    class ListenerType, 
    class CommandBusType = typename copy_template_params<ListenerType,CommandBus>::type
>
class CommandBusFactory
{
  public:
    static auto Get()
    {
        return CommandBusType{};
    }
};
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate on how does this works? It seems a bit complicated.
I see that you have a templated structure that accepts a type X and a template template type. Also you have a specialized version that accepts multiple things.
Could you explain what happens in more detail please?
For example what happens when I use CommandBusFactory<Listener<int,int,int,int>>::Get();
???

Comment: I would like to approve this as the correct result but I still don't fully understand this answer. Is the second template structure partially specialized? I don't get it.

Comment: @GabrielGrigoras I'm not sure what to explain. The specialization is for the first template parameter being a specialized template with 4 arguments. `copy_template_params<Listener<int,int,int,int>,CommandBus>::type` expands to `CommandBus<int,int,int,int>`.

Comment: what's the purpose of the first template class?

Comment: @GabrielGrigoras To apply/copy template parameters from a specific specialization of `Listener<...>` to `CommandBus<...>`.

Answer (score 1):

It is not entirely clear what you are attempting here. The use of the template there will allow `CommandBusFactory` to create different instantiations of the provided `ListenerType`, rather than for them to be passed in, e.g.:

```
template <
    template<class T1, class T2, class T3, class T4> class ListenerType,
    class CommandBusType
>
class CommandBusFactory {
    static auto Get() {
        ListenerType<int, int, float, float> listener; // template params go here
        ListenerType<std::string, std::string, double, double> listener2; // allowing different ones
        return CommandBusType{};
    }
};
int main() {
    CommandBusFactory<Listener, SomeCommandBus> factory; // not here
}
```

If you do want to provide the `ListenerType` up front, and then determine `CommandBusType` from that, you might use typedefs, return values, or similar means (like containers having `value_type`, etc.).

```
template<class T1, class T2, class T3, class T4> class CommandBus {};
template<class T1, class T2, class T3, class T4> class Listener
{
public:
    typedef T1 t1;
    typedef T2 t2;
    typedef T3 t3;
    typedef T4 t4;
};
template <
    class ListenerType,
    class CommandBusType = CommandBus<typename ListenerType::t1, typename ListenerType::t2, typename ListenerType::t3, typename ListenerType::t4>
>
class CommandBusFactory {
    static auto Get() {
        return CommandBusType{};
    }
};

int main() {
    CommandBusFactory<Listener<int,int,float,float>> factory;
}
```