# Deducing the size of an array when a template template parameter is used

Tags: c++, arrays, size, template-templates

A very simple method to find the number of elements in a template array is shown in the following discussion:

[How does this function template deduce the size of an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2384107/how-does-this-function-template-deduce-the-size-of-an-array)

I wanted to emulate the same method to get the number of elements in my template template array:

```
//classA.h

#include <type_traits>
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>

using std::is_same;
using std::size_t;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

template<typename T> class A;
template<typename T>
using array2As = A<T>[2];

template<template<typename T>class A, size_t N>
size_t cal_size(A<T>*&[N]){
 return N;
}

template<typename T>
class A{
  public:
  A(T);
  private:
  A()=delete;
  A(const A&)=delete; 
  A& operator=(const A&)=delete;
  T elem;
};

template<typename T>
A<T>::A(T elem){
  static_assert(is_same<T,int>::value || is_same<T,double>::value, "Compilation error: type must be int or double");
  this->elem = elem;
}


#include "classA.h"

int main (){
 
 array2As<int> a = {A(5),A(7)};
 auto sz = cal_size(a); 
 array2As<double> b = {A(1.2),A(6.3)};
 auto sz = cal_size(b); 

 return 0;
}
```

For the above code I get the following compiler error:

```
In file included from main.cpp:1:
classA.h:18:19: error: ‘T’ was not declared in this scope
   18 | size_t cal_size(A<T>*&[N]){
      |                   ^
compilation terminated due to -Wfatal-errors.
```

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: An even better solution is to use `std::array` and its `size()` function... ;-) And instead of using both the array member type and size, just use a single container template argument, then the function can be called with any suitable container.

Comment: Also note that since the C++17 standard, there's the [`std::size`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/size) function which can be used instead of inventing your own.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I have already tried std::size and it doesn't work with the template template array shown in my example...or better put, I couldn't figure out how to manipulate the template template array in my example to feed into std::size to get the number of elements

Comment: Oh, and passing an array by reference means it will not decay to a pointer. The normal way to declare an array-size function is simply `T(&)[N]`. Note the parentheses, it's a reference to an array, not an array of references. For your case it would be something like `A<T>(&)[N]`.

Comment: [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Ea5vhaoYG) with `std::size`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude The compiler was showing the type of the argument as A<T>*&, reference to pointer to the first element?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`T` in `template <typename T> class A` doesn't introduce `T`. It is unused. you have to introduce `typename T`.

It should be

```
template <template <typename> class A, typename T, size_t N>
size_t cal_size(const A<T>(&)[N]){
     return N;
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/qn5nMPf1a)

Answer (score 1):

The template template parameter needs to be introducted in the template template parameter list:

```cpp
template <template <typename> class A, class T, size_t N>
// no name needed   ^^^^^^^^           ^^^^^^^ this is needed
constexpr size_t cal_size(A<T>(&)[N]) {
    return N;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The parameter names in a template template parameter are useless in your case.
In the parameter:

> ```cpp
> template<typename T> class A
> ```

... `typename T` introduces the name `T`, but only in the scope of the pointy brackets. `T` is only visible inside `template<...>`, not outside of it. See also [Is there any use for named parameters into template template parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28992265/5740428).
It cannot be deduced from `A<T>` because the name doesn't exist in that scope.

As @Jarod42 has said, you *could* write

> ```cpp
> template <template <typename> class A, typename T, size_t N>
> ```

But this wouldn't have any advantage over using the function from the question you've linked.
Note that C++17 has introduced [`std::size`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/size), which works exactly like the linked function:

```cpp
std::size_t sz = std::size(a);
```

---

*Note: the `A` template template parameter, and the `A` class template aren't necessarily the same. They just share a name by coincidence.*

Comment: The only "advantage" is to check type of the array element, i.e `A<T>`.

Comment: @Jarod42 yeah sure, you could add an additional constraint to the function which verifies that. In its current state, the `A` template template parameter just happens to be the same as the `A` class template, but there is no strict relation between the two. Using a template template parameter would merely verify that *some* class template was used which accepts a `typename` parameter, and that seems like an artificial and rarely useful constraint on its own. Personally, I would prefer a constraint on `::value_type` for the elements.