# Template parameter for a class which is also a template parameter

Tags: c++, templates

I try to do the following, I think the example should be self-explaining:

```
template <class CLASS, class PARAM>
void call(){
  CLASS<PARAM>::do_something();
}
```

On the angular brackets between CLASS and PARAM on line 3, the compiler says:

> error: expected unqualified-id

Can I fix this problem or is it not allowed what I try to do?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are some uses of template template parameters in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/213761/what-are-some-uses-of-template-template-parameters-in-c)

Comment: How do you expect to *use* this?  Perhaps `call<vector,int>()`? Or `call< vector<int> >()`? The latter is possible with changes to the signature of `call`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The template parameter `CLASS` is declared to be a `class`, or also a `typename`, I.e. the name of a type.

```
template<typename X> struct A;
```

Here `A` isn't a type, it's a template. To obtain a type, you need to "apply"(*) the template: `A<int>`.

If you write `CLASS<PARAM>`, you're trying to apply a type to a type. This won't work. It's like trying to call a value `42(parameter)`, only on the type level.

So you need to specify that `CLASS` is something which can be applied, that it's a template:

```
template <typename T> class CLASS
```

So, for reference, the complete solution is:

```
template <template <typename T> class CLASS, class PARAM>
void call(){
  CLASS<PARAM>::do_something();
}
```

(*) A template is a function on type level: It takes one or more types, and returns a new type.

Answer (score 4):

```
template <
    template <typename T> class CLASS,
    typename PARAM>
void call()
{
    CLASS<PARAM>::do_something();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answers given by @DanielJour and @Nasser, I want to mention that the name `T` of the type name for the template template parameter `CLASS` can be omitted, because it is not used. So, the condensed solution would look like this:

```
template <template <typename> class CLASS, typename PARAM>
void call()
{
    CLASS<PARAM>::do_something();
}
```

Reference: [Template Template Parameters](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=376878).