# Breaking template circular dependencies by using template template parameters

Tags: c++, templates

If my understanding is correct, the following is a classical circular dependency between template classes:

```
template <class MyB>
struct A {
    MyB *b_;
};

template <class MyA>
struct B {
    MyA *a_;
};
```

If we want to instantiate `A` with `B` and `B` with `A`, then we can't begin with either one, since we would have to write: `A<B<A<B<...>>>` (infinite).

I think that template template parameters provide a solution. The following code compiles (with `gcc` version 4.8.2):

```
template <class MyB>
struct A {
    MyB *b_;
};

template <template <class> class MyA>
struct B {
    MyA<B> *a_;
};

int main() {
    using MyB = B<A>;
    using MyA = A<MyB>;
    MyA a;
    MyB b;
    a.b_ = &b; b.a_ = &a;
    return 0;
}
```

Am I missing the essence of the problem?

**UPDATE**: I just ran into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23930985/2725810) post which proposes essentially the same solution.

Answer (score 2):

I would try to design my code in order to avoid those circular dependencies. Anyway if prompted with a compelling reason not to, there are several ways of solve this issue:

- As you noted, using a template template parameter solves the problem by breaking the cycle

  ```
  template <class MyB>
  struct A {
      MyB *b_;
  };

  template <template <class> class MyA>
  struct B {
      MyA<B> *a_;
  };

  int main() {
      using MyB = B<A>;
      using MyA = A<MyB>;
      MyA a;
      MyB b;
      a.b_ = &b; b.a_ = &a;
      return 0;
  }
  ```
- Another solution could be to encapsulate the types you need into an external struct/class

  ```
  template<class Common> struct A
  {
    typedef typename Common::BT B;
    B* b;
  };

  template<class Common> struct B
  {
    typedef typename Common::AT A;
    A* a;
  };

  struct Common {
    using AT = A<Common>;
    using BT = B<Common>;
  };


  int main() {
    A<Common> a;
    B<Common> b;
    return 0;
  }
  ```
- Depending on what the rest of your code does, in a simple case like this you might get away with variadic templates

  ```
  template <class MyA>
  struct B;

  template <typename ...MyB>
  struct A {
    B<A<>> *b_;
  };

  template <>
  struct A<> {};

  template <class MyA>
  struct B {
    A<B<MyA>> *a_;
  };

  int main() {

    using BoA = B<A<>>;
    using AoBoA = A<B<A<>>>;

    BoA obj1;
    AoBoA obj2;

    obj1.a_ = &obj2;
    obj2.b_ = &obj1;

    return 0;
  }
  ```

Finally it's worth to be noted that exposing a common base class and using a [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern)-like approach could probably be the cleaner way to achieve this (you might even gain points for clarity and readability).