# Should template template parameters be used for a policy with a state?

Tags: c++, templates

As pointed out by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/214900/2725810) post, in ['Modern C++ Design - Generic Programming and Design Patterns Applied'](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201704315), Andrei Alexandrescu uses classes with template template parameters to implement the policy pattern:

```
// Library code
template <template <class> class CreationPolicy>
class WidgetManager : public CreationPolicy<Widget>
{
   ...
};
```

Now, suppose that the policy class has a state (i.e. it has non-static members) and that the host class stores an object of the policy class:

```
// Library code
template <template <class> class Logger>
struct Algorithm
{
   Algorithm(Logger<Event> &logger) : logger_(logger) {}
   ...
   private:
       Logger<Event> &logger_; 
};
```

The user will probably write something like this:

```
using MyLogger = ConcreteLogger<MyEvent>;
MyLogger log;
Algorithm<ConcreteLogger> alg(log);
```

Since the user needs to instantiate `ConcreteLogger`, is there any remaining advantage in using template template parameter in this case?

Comment: Template template parameters usually aren't as useful as type parameters, as you just discovered. Typical examples for using type parameters to pass policy *objects* (not types) can be found in the standard library, namely in the way predicates are passed to algorithms, and allocators to containers.

Comment: @KerrekSB Thank you for the confirmation.