# template template arguments: no matching call found

Tags: c++, templates

```
#include <vector>

using std::vector;

template<template<typename> class x>
void test() {
    x<int> a;
    a.push_back(1);
}

int main() {
    test<vector>();
    return 0;
}
```

For some reason, I get no matching call error, despite my expectations. Why does this happen?

Comment: Where is the type `x` defined? Why are you `return`ing from a `void` function?

Comment: Take a look at std::vector declaration.

Comment: What are you trying to do in test function.. ?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/213761/what-are-some-uses-of-template-template-parameters-in-c for some syntax inspiration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) does not take one argument, but two (there is `Allocator`), so it cannot be matched against a template that should take only one. You need to change to either:

```
template <template <typename, typename> class x>
// or:
template <template <typename... > class x>
```

You also need to change the return type of your function because it is unlikely that `x<int>` is `void`.

Note that if you use the version with two `typename`, you would need to specify each parameters in the return statement (e.g. `x<int, std::allocator<int>>`), which is why you should prefer the variadic version (`typename...`).

Comment: So I should list each and every template parameter?

Comment: @RomaValcer Yes, or use a variadic version.

Answer (score 2):

std::vector template looks as follows:

```
template<
    class T,
    class Allocator = std::allocator<T>
> class vector;
```

so you have typename T and allocator for it, so the correct code should be:

```
template<template<typename,typename> class x>
void test() {
    x<int, std::allocator<int>>();
}
```