# Deduce a class enum for generic types

Tags: c++, templates

Consider this simple, but complete example:

```
#include <iostream>

enum class Foo
{
    A,
    B
};

template <Foo F>
struct X{};

template <Foo F>
constexpr Foo deduce_foo(X<F>&& arg)
{
    return F;
}

int main()
{
    if ( deduce_foo(X<Foo::B>{}) == Foo::A )
        std::cout << "A";
    else
        std::cout << "B";
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

which deduces the `enum class` correctly (function `deduce_foo(...)`).

Now, I want to make it more generic, substituting X by a template T, i.e:

```
template <Foo F, typename T>
constexpr Foo deduce_foo(T<F>&& arg) { ... }
```

But compiler (g++ 7.3.0) gives me this error:

> error: ‘T’ is not a template
>   constexpr Foo deduce_foo(X&& arg)

What Im doing wrong?

Comment: Your `typename T` isn't actually a "typename".  It's a template, not the name of a specific type.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213761

Comment: It should be `template <Foo F, template<Foo> class C>
constexpr Foo deduce_foo(C<F>&& arg) { ... }`

Comment: @Jarod42 Thanks, worked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to declare that T is a template, try:

```
template <Foo F, template<Foo> class T>
constexpr Foo deduce_foo(T<F>&& arg)
{
    return F;
}
```