# What is the template syntax for an arbitrary container of doubles?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

I have a function that rounds a value according to a policy

```
double round(double f, Policy p);
```

What I want to do now is to build a version of this that can be applied only to a container of doubles (there's no point in having a container of any other type due to the way the rounding works).

```
template <class Iterable>
Iterable<double> round(
    Iterable<double> y, Policy p){
    for (auto&& e : y){
        e = round(e, p);
    }
    return y;
}
```

I know my template syntax is not correct, but what should it be?

Comment: Here is your answer, I think, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213761/what-are-some-uses-of-template-template-parameters

Comment: You don't have to specify anything about `y`, just write `for (double & d : y)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use template-template parameters:

```
#include <vector>

template <template <typename...> class Container, typename T>
auto round(Container<T> y){
    for (auto&& e : y){
        // ...
    }
    return y;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<double> vec = {1.1, 2.2};
    std::vector<double> rounded = round(vec);
}
```

[live on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bcb3fe1b07655f49)

Comment: the OP specifically asked to restrict the use to only containers of `double`. Your code has no problem to compile for `std::vector<int>`.

Comment: It is nonetheless an elegant solution. The OP could always static_assert on `T` if they insisted.