# C++ - Template static method with templated parameter inside template class

Tags: c++, templates

I have these two classes:

```
template <typename GeomType>
class InputCSV
{
public:
    InputCSV(DataSet<GeomType> * ds) : ds(ds) {}
    virtual ~InputLoaderCSV() = default;

    DataSet<GeomType> * ds;
};
```

and

```
template <typename GeomType>
struct DataSet
{
    template <typename LoaderType>
    static DataSet<GeomType> Create()
    {
        DataSet<GeomType> ds;
        ds.fileName = "something";
        ds.input = std::make_shared<LoaderType<GeomType>>(&ds);
        return std::move(ds);
    };

    DataSet(const DataSet & ds) = delete;

    DataSet(DataSet && ds)
    {
        this->fileName = std::move(ds.fileName);
        this->input = std::move(ds.input);
        this->input->ds = this;

        ds.input = nullptr;     
    }

    std::string fileName;
    std::shared_ptr<InputLoader<GeomType>> input;

   protected:   
        DataSet() : input(nullptr) {}
}
```

Now somewhere in code, I want to do

```
auto ds = DataSet<Line>::Create<InputCSV>();
```

where Line is some struct I have. However, this is not working and I got this error:

```
error C2672: 'DataSet<Line>::Create': no matching overloaded function found
error C3206: 'DataSet<Line>::Create': invalid template argument for 'LoaderType', missing template argument list on class template 'InputLoaderCSV'
note: see declaration of 'DataSet<Line>::Create' 
error cannot access protected member declared in class 'DataSet<Line>'
note: see declaration of 'DataSet<Line>::DataSet' note: see declaration of 'DataSet<Line>'
```

Is there any solution to have this kind of "syntax", or I have to write

```
auto ds = DataSet<Line>::Create<InputCSV<Line>>();
```

and change

```
ds.input = std::make_shared<LoaderType<GeomType>>(&ds);
```

to

```
ds.input = std::make_shared<LoaderType>(&ds);
```

In this example, I donw like "duplication" of  in InputCSV, since there cannot be anything else.

Comment: Shouldn't it be something like `template <template<typename> LoaderType>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is a [template template parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213761/what-are-some-uses-of-template-template-parameters).  Since `InputCSV` is a template type, you have to specify its template parameter.  If you change `Create` to use a template template parameter instead then you can pass the template to `Create` and use it like you would any other template.  To do that you need to use

```
template <template<typename> typename LoaderType>
// pre C++17 you have to use template <template<class> class LoaderType> instead
static DataSet<GeomType> Create()
{
    DataSet<GeomType> ds;
    ds.fileName = "something";
    ds.input = std::make_shared<LoaderType<GeomType>>(&ds);
    return std::move(ds);
}
```

and then you keep the use as

```
auto ds = DataSet<Line>::Create<InputCSV>();
```

and now `LoaderType` is a template type that takes a single template parameter that you can specify inside the function.

Comment: Thank you, it is working, but I have to use `template <template<typename> typename LoaderType>`

Comment: @MartinPerry Yep.  Fixed.  I don't use them often so I get the syntax wrong sometimes.

Comment: @NathanOliver Would it be OK to mark the question as dupe of that link you have in your answer?

Comment: Also, using `...typename LoaderType>` is a new C++17 thing. Before that, you had to use `...class LoaderType>`

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I didn't think it was enough for a dupe but if you do it's your vote.

Comment: @SergeyA Fixed.

Comment: @NathanOliver Together with your explanation, I believe it's a good signpost for the duplicate network. I'll hammer it.