# Use Current Template as a Template Parameter to one of the Template Parameters

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17, circular-dependency

I am trying to make a generic graph structure, but I am running into this circular dependency between vertices and edges. I define my Vertex and Edge classes like so:

```cpp
template<typename EdgeType>
struct Vertex {
    std::vector<EdgeType> successors;
};

template<typename EdgeCostType, typename VertexWrapper>
struct Edge {
    EdgeCostType cost;
    VertexWrapper source;
    VertexWrapper dest;
};
```

I would like to instantiate it with something like `Vertex<Edge<int, std::shared_ptr<decltype(v)>>> v;`, but I obviously cannot. What can I do to resolve this circular dependency?

Edit:

I think what this problem boils down to is using the current template as a template parameter to one of the template parameters of the current template, e.g. how to do something like this:

```cpp
template<typename VertexWrapper>
struct Vertex {
    std::vector<pair<int, VertexWrapper<Vertex>>> successors;
};
```

Comment: `template <typename> class VertexWrapper`? Also, why do you have both C++11 and C++17 tags? Which standard are you targeting?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Afaik both apply, should I only use the most recent one? Also I'm not sure what you mean by `template <typename> typename VertexWrapper`

Comment: Is the `VertexWrapper` type argument always supposed to be of the form `std::shared_ptr<decltype(v)>` or `some_template_here<decltype(v)>`?

Comment: @walnut it should be something like shared_ptr/unique_ptr/something with operator->

Comment: If I'm reading this question right, you might want to look into "template template" parameters

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213761/what-are-some-uses-of-template-template-parameters

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With template template parameter, you can do something like:

```
template<typename EdgeType>
struct Vertex {
    std::vector<EdgeType> successors;
};

template<typename EdgeCostType, template <typename> class VertexWrapper>
struct Edge {
    EdgeCostType cost;
    VertexWrapper<Edge> source;
    VertexWrapper<Edge> dest;
};


using myEdge = Edge<double, Vertex>;
using myVertex = Vertex<myEdge>;
```

Comment: Thanks! TIL about template template parameters

Answer (score 2):

yours simply works..  (but i don't know how to print and initialize member vector)

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>  
using namespace std;

template<typename EdgeType>
struct Vertex {
    vector<EdgeType> successors;
};

template<typename EdgeCostType, typename VertexWrapper>
struct Edge {
    EdgeCostType cost;
    VertexWrapper source;
    VertexWrapper dest;
};

int main (){

    Vertex<int> vertx = {{5}};
    Edge<int, decltype(vertx)> ed = {7};

    cout<< ed.cost <<"\n";     //cout<< ed.dest.successors<<"\n";   // not work, ask help!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Jarod42's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59549217/10957435) will work, but it does constrain you to only doubles. If you want a more flexible one that accepts `int`s, for instance, you also have this option:

```
template<class T>
using myEdge = Edge<T, Vertex>;

template<class T>
using myVertex = Vertex<myEdge<T>>;
```

This will allow you to use other types of numbers, if for some reason you need a shorthand for that. Then using doubles would look like this:

```
myVertex<double> v;
```

Comment: It was just an example usage. To go further, I would do `template <typename T> struct graph_type { using egde = Edge<T, Vertex>; using vertex = Vertex<edge>; };`