# How to check uniqueness of types of template template parameter?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, type-traits, typechecking

I have the following code to check the uniqueness of template parameters:

```
template <typename ...Tn>
struct uniq_types 
{
    static constexpr const bool value = true;
};

template <typename T1, typename T2, typename ...Tn>
struct uniq_types<T1, T2, Tn...> 
{
    static constexpr const bool value
        = !std::is_same<T1, T2>::value && uniq_types<T1, Tn...>::value && uniq_types<T2, Tn...>::value;
};

template <typename T>
struct uniq_types<T> 
{
    static constexpr const bool value = true;
};
```

It works fine.  But then, if I want to check the uniqueness of the template parameters of a container, `std::tuple` for example, I need to partially specialize it like:

```
template <typename ...Tn>
struct uniq_types<std::tuple<Tn...>> : public uniq_types<Tn...> 
{
};
```

I wonder whether there is a way to do so without partial specialization for every container.

I have tried

```
template <template <typename...> typename U, typename... Tn>
struct unique_types;

template <template <typename T1, typename T2, typename... Tn> typename U,
                    typename T1, typename T2, typename... Tn>
struct unique_types<U, T1, T2, Tn...> 
{
    static constexpr const bool value 
        = !std::is_same<T1, T2>::value && unique_types<U, T1, Tn...>::value && unique_types<U, T2, Tn...>::value;
};

template <template <typename T> typename U, typename T>
struct unique_types<U, T> 
{
    static constexpr const bool value = true;
};
```

It works, but then to check, I have to "expand" the template parameters of the container like this:

```
unique_types<std::tuple, int>::value
```

I would like to do something like this:

```
unique_types<std::tuple<int>>::value; // true
unique_types<std::tuple<int, double>>::value; // true
unique_types<std::tuple<int, double, int>>::value; // false
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make the traits to specialise for the [template template parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213761/what-are-some-uses-of-template-template-parameters). Then using [`std::conjunction`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conjunction) you can do this

```
#include <type_traits> // std::is_same, std::conjunction_v

template<typename Type, typename... Rs>
constexpr bool areSameTypes = std::conjunction_v<std::is_same<Type, Rs>...>;

template <typename T>
struct unique_types : std::false_type {};

template <template<typename...> class Container, typename... V>
struct unique_types<Container<V...>>
{
   constexpr static bool value = areSameTypes<V...>;
};
```

Now you could

```
static_assert(unique_types<std::tuple<int>>::value, "not unique");
static_assert(unique_types<std::tuple<int, int, int>>::value, "not unique");
// static_assert(unique_types<std::tuple<int, char, int>>::value, "not unique");  // error
```

[See a demo](https://godbolt.org/z/9r5oKn)

Comment: Thanks.  My question probably wasn't too clear -- I was actually asking for checking whether types of all template template parameters are unique.  Your solution checks whether all have the same types.  +1 for pointing out `std::conjunction_v`.

Comment: I think I can just modify your solution with `std::negation` in front of `std::is_same`.

Comment: actually, I think even with `std::negation`, it won't work.  For instance, gcc and clang 10.0 compiles `static_assert(unique_types<std::tuple<int, bool, bool, char>>::value)` without an error.  I think the problem is that `std::conjunction_v<std::negation<std::is_same<Type, Rs>>...>` is compiled into `!std::is_same<Type, R1>::value> && `!std::is_same<Type, R2>::value> && `!std::is_same<Type, R3>::value>`...so it does not create a conjunction of permutation of all types with `std::same`.

Answer (score 0):

There is the std::type_index wrapper around std::type_info which is a data type returned from typeid() operator. It will index types for the lifetime of the program afaik.

```
std::type_index(typeid(T));
```

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_index

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with something like this

```
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename ...Tn>
struct uniq_types 
{
    static constexpr const bool value = true;
};

template <typename T1, typename T2, typename ...Tn>
struct uniq_types<T1, T2, Tn...> 
{
    static constexpr const bool value
        = !std::is_same<T1, T2>::value && uniq_types<T1, Tn...>::value && uniq_types<T2, Tn...>::value;
};

template <typename T>
struct uniq_types<T> 
{
    static constexpr const bool value = true;
};

template <typename T>
struct unique_types : uniq_types<T> {
    static constexpr const bool value = uniq_types<T>::value;
};

template <template <typename...> typename C, typename... Tn>
struct unique_types<C<Tn...>> {
    static constexpr const bool value = uniq_types<Tn...>::value;
};

int main() {
    static_assert(unique_types<std::tuple<int>>::value); // okay
    static_assert(unique_types<std::tuple<int, bool, bool, char>>::value); // error
}
```