# How to avoid this kind of code repetition?

Tags: c++, class, c++11, templates, class-template

In order to avoid code repetition, I need to do something like this (in my real code I have much more complex types similar to `T1` and `T2`):

```
template <class T1, class T2>
struct A 
{};

template <class T1, class T2>
struct B 
{};

template <class X>
struct C 
{
   using p1 = int;
   using p2 = char;

   using some = X<p1, p2>;
};

int main()
{
   C<A> o1; // must produce C<A<int,char> >
   C<B> o2; // must produce C<B<int,char> >
}
```

Comment: Is that supposed to be `C<A>::some o1;` and `C<B>::some o2;`?

Comment: typo fixed now is OK

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your class `C` needs to use a [template template parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213761/what-are-some-uses-of-template-template-parameters) in order to accept `A` and `B` as input to its own template so it can then pass parameters to them, eg:

```
template <template<typename T1, typename T2> class X>
struct C 
{
   using p1 = int;
   using p2 = char;

   using some = X<p1, p2>;
};
```

Now you can do this:

```
C<A> o1; // produce C<A<int,char> >
C<B> o2; // produce C<B<int,char> >
```

[See a demo](https://godbolt.org/z/hcdfrM)

Comment: Wow... Is that standard feature?

Comment: @Nick Yes [indeed](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters#Template_template_arguments), and here [more read from std](http://eel.is/c++draft//temp.arg.template)