# Template template parameters validity

Tags: c++, templates

```
template <template <typename> class CallbackT,
      typename Functor,
      typename... Args>
decltype(auto) BindImpl(Functor&& functor, Args&&... args)
```

BindImpl is a template function, and is called like this:

```
return internal::BindImpl<OnceCallback>(std::forward<Functor>(functor),
                                        std::forward<Args>(args)...);
```

as far as I know, [template template paramaters are not allowed in a template function](https://zh.wikipedia.org/zh-cn/%E6%A8%A1%E6%9D%BF%E7%9A%84%E6%A8%A1%E6%9D%BF%E5%8F%82%E6%95%B0).

What kind of mechanism is used here?

[see source code here](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/master:base/bind.h;l=252;drc=66b4a77751e82213fe0850f143619eb372402466;bpv=0;bpt=1)

Comment: "template template paramaters is not allowed to be used in template function." -- do you have some source on that? I think it should be allowed.

Comment: *"template template paramaters is not allowed to be used in template function"* Citation needed.

Comment: Please post your citation in english

Comment: Citation added, but there is only Chinese version.

Comment: Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213761/what-are-some-uses-of-template-template-parameters)

Comment: If Chinese Wikipedia does indeed say that (seems to be the case), then it's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The code is correct, as there is no restriction as the Chinese Wikipedia article describes. Regretfully I cannot update the article, as my IP address is banned. You should delete that sentence if you can.