# Is there a way to use variable template as a parameter?

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, sfinae

I want to declare a function, which will take as a parameter a variable (let's say, `int`), which should be parametrized by a class. Speaking in terms of lambda calculus, I want my parameter to have a kind `* -> int`.

Example of a function I want to be able to write (`Spec` is the variable):

```
template <??? Specification, typename T>
auto make_array() {
    return std::array<T, Specification<T>>;
}
```

Since C++14 we have variable templates, so we can do something like this:

```
template <typename T>
constexpr int digits = std::numeric_limits<T>::digits;
```

The problem is, how do I pass that into a function? In the notes section of [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/variable_template) it is stated that

> Variable templates cannot be used as template template arguments.

But does that mean that there is actually no way to pass parametrized variable as a function parameter? What you can do is, for example, create a class which has a static field denoting value, but an obvious drawback is that the users of my function must derive from that class.

I believe there might be some workaround using SFINAE, but I lack skills in that area.

Comment: wording is a bit confusing because you are talking about a function parameter but code looks like you want a template parameter also the quote is about tempalte parameter

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are some uses of template template parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213761/what-are-some-uses-of-template-template-parameters)

Comment: @idclev463035818 I am curious about any way to implement such a functionality, but I guess it can be considered a template parameter.

Comment: @Sprite Along with the provided answer, it does answer my question.

Comment: your example uses `int` because you want to pass the "value of `specification<T>`" as template parameter to `std::array`, right? Note that the parameter of `std::array` is `size_t` not `int` (I first made the same mistake in my answer)

Answer (score 4):

Unless you insist on using a variable template, you can use a type trait:

```
template <typename T> struct Specification;
```

you can specialize it for example for `int`:

```
template <>
struct Specification<int> {
    static constexpr size_t value = 42;
};
```

and as you want to have different `Specification`s, pass it as template template parameter:

```
template <template<class> class S, typename T>
auto make_array() {
    return std::array<T, S<T>::value>{};
}
```

[Complete example](https://godbolt.org/z/MbcdnM):

```
#include <array>
#include <cstddef>

template <template<class> class S, typename T>
auto make_array() {
    return std::array<T, S<T>::value>{};
}

template <typename T> struct Specification;

template <>
struct Specification<int> {
    static constexpr size_t value = 42;
};

int main(){
  auto x = make_array<Specification,int>();  
}
```

Note that I was rather verbose for the sake of clarity. You can save a bit of typing by using [`std::integral_constant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integral_constant), eg:

```
template <>
struct Specification<double> : std::integral_constant<size_t,3> {};
```

Comment: Thank you! This solution allows me to use multiple specifications, and that is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Note you don't necessarily need specializations here, either: in this example using `template <typename T> struct digits : std::integral_constant<int, std::numeric_limits<T>::digits> {};` instead of a variable template would allow you to use `digits` exactly as you wanted to anyway.

Comment: @N.Shead OP wants different specifications. With your solution, how would you pass different variants of `digits` to `make_array`? Anyhow I think your comment adresses the wrong user, isnt this for OP? If you have a better solution, please post an answer. I don't understand yet how your code in the comment answers the quesiton

Comment: @idclev463035818 yes, that was meant to be for OP. But my assumption is that they would choose between `digits` or `size : std::integral_constant<int, sizeof(T)> {}` or so forth: different specifications as "variable templates" rather than specifications as "results for a given T"

Comment: @N.Shead sorry I cannot follow you. Would be nice if you expanded this to an answer

Comment: @idclev463035818 expanded in an answer; hopefully that makes my point clearer! Apologies for the confusion.

Comment: Been doing this for decades and template syntax still gives me a headache.

Comment: @3Dave I am doing this since not so long, SFINAE still causes me headaces and most modern stuff that came with C++20 is worse than headaces. It almost feels like once you got the hang of it there is something radically different to do the same ;)

Comment: @idclev463035818 "This is the way." :)

Answer (score 1):

As an follow-up on [idclev's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65012830/4117728), you can avoid the need to explicitly specialise for the different types for individual "specifications" just by inheriting from e.g. `integral_constant`. For example, your desired usage was something like

```cpp
template <template <typename T> int Specification, typename T>
auto make_array() {
    return std::array<T, Specification<T>>;
}

template <typename T>
constexpr int digits = std::numeric_limits<T>::digits;

// ...

auto foo = make_array<digits, double>();
```

However, as you have noted, this is impossible: you cannot pass variable templates as template-template parameters. However, by turning `digits` into a structure directly you can do this:

```cpp
template <template <typename T> class Specification, typename T>
auto make_array() {
    // we no longer have the guarantee of the type here, unfortunately
    // but you can use a static_assert to improve error messages
    // (also using `std::size_t` here for correctness)
    static_assert(
        std::is_convertible<decltype(Specification<T>::value), std::size_t>::value,
        "value must be convertible to size_t");
    
    return std::array<T, Specification<T>::value>;
}

// use a type rather than a variable template
// we just inherit from integral constant to save on some typing
// (though you could do this explicitly as well)
template <typename T>
struct digits : std::integral_constant<int, std::numeric_limits<T>::digits> {};

// ...

// same call!
auto foo = make_array<digits, double>();
```

Comment: you assume that OP always wants  `std::numeric_limits<T>::digits` if that would be the case, you need not pass anything to `make_array` in addition to `T`, you could use `std::numeric_limits<T>::digits` directly inside `make_array`. I suppose the part about `std::numeric_limits<T>::digits` in the question was just a random  example for a variable template

Comment: @idclev463035818 I don't assume that, though? They could just as well do `struct size : std::integral_constant<int, sizeof(digits)> {};` instead and call `make_array<size, double>();` — there's nothing stopping them?

Comment: ok, sorry I was confused. But still your answer is basically the same as mine. Only if one of the desired specifications *is* `std::numerical_limits<T>::digits` you need not specialize "manually". Otherwise I dont see the difference

Comment: @idclev463035818 Yes, it is. That's why I just left it as a comment :)

Comment: ok sorry, for being a bit stubborn ;). Code in comments is really hard to understand...

Comment: @idclev463035818 just one last thing: they would only need to specialise, ever, if their original variable templates that they were trying to use were specialised. As in, specialisation is the "extension" to the general rule of using variable templates. Otherwise why would they not just be doing `make_array<3, int>();` or whatever directly?

Comment: what is above and below depends on each users sorting. In my view there is no answer above yours. Also user names can change, so better use a link