# How to template containers?

Tags: c++, templates

I have this function that I'd like to use for a container of strings, like `vector<string>` or `set<string>`. Obviously templating seems like the best solution here but I'm not sure how to template the container. I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
template<class T>
string pack_addrs(T<string>& caddrs) {
  string res = "";
  for (string addr : caddrs) {
    res += addr + ",";
  }
  return res.substr(0, res.size()-1);
}
```

Comment: IMHO, the function is not recommended.  For example, there isn't a standard method to insert into a container.  Also, I don't believe the savings of this function is worth the hassle and development time.

Comment: Take a look at the `<algorithm>` header of the standard library. Can you see a single algorithm that receives a container argument? No? There is a reason for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can allow your template to use any class generically, but assert that it must behave like a container. In particular, you can assert that it has a `value_type` that matches `std::string`.

```
template<class C>
std::string pack_addrs(C& caddrs) {
  static_assert(std::is_same<typename C::value_type, std::string>::value);
  std::string res = "";
  for (std::string addr : caddrs) {
    res += addr + ",";
  }
  return res.substr(0, res.size()-1);
}
```

Or, you can use SFINAE to disable the function if the type of the argument does not match the desired trait.

```
template<class C,
         typename std::enable_if<
             std::is_same<typename C::value_type,
                          std::string>::value>::type* = nullptr>
std::string pack_addrs(C& caddrs) {
  std::string res = "";
  for (std::string addr : caddrs) {
    res += addr + ",";
  }
  return res.substr(0, res.size()-1);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

When a template parameter is itself a templated type, you can use a [template template parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213761/) for it, eg:

```cpp
template <template<class...> class Container>
string pack_addrs(const Container<string>& caddrs) {
  string res;
  for (const string &addr : caddrs) {
    res += addr + ",";
  }
  return res.substr(0, res.size()-1);
}
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/OfUq1K)

This code will allow you to pass in any templated container that accepts `std::string` as its 1st template parameter (even if it takes additional template parameters, like an allocator, etc), and that satisfies the requirements of a [range-for loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for).