# Multiple template functions with enable_if and is_same and with missing argument list of the class template in C++

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae

I have the following code which compiles nicely:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

struct Res {};
struct Jac {};

template <typename T, typename S>
class A;

template <typename S>
class A<Res, S>
{
    public:
        A() { std::cout << "A<Res, S>" << std::endl; }
};

template <typename S>
class A<Jac, S>
{
    public:
        A() { std::cout << "A<Jac, S>" << std::endl; }
};



template <typename T, typename S>
class B;

template <typename S>
class B<Res, S>
{
    public:
        B() { std::cout << "B<Res, S>" << std::endl; }
};

template <typename S>
class B<Jac, S>
{
    public:
        B() { std::cout << "B<Jac, S>" << std::endl; }
};


template<typename S, typename EvalT,
    std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<EvalT, A<Res,S>>::value, bool> = true
>
void foo() 
{
    A<Res, S> a_res;
    A<Jac, S> a_jac;
}

template<typename S, typename EvalT,
    std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<EvalT, B<Res,S>>::value, bool> = true
>
void foo()
{
    B<Res, S> b_res;
    B<Jac, S> b_jac;
}

int main() {

    foo<int, A<Res,int>>();
    foo<int, B<Res,int>>();

    return 0;
}
```

However I am not happy with the calls inside my `main()` function. I would like them to look like this:

```cpp
    foo<int, A>();
    foo<int, B>();
```

which would imply the following modification of the templates for `foo()`:

```cpp
template<typename S, typename EvalT,
    std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<EvalT, B>::value, bool> = true
>
void foo()
{
    B<Res, S> b_res;
    B<Jac, S> b_jac;
}
```

This obviously does not compile. The idea is to have a function, which would instantiate either `A` or `B` without explicitly specifying `T` for my classes because I know that `foo()` has to create 2 instances with `Res` and `Jac` as type parameters. Is there any way to make the code neater and achieve such a behavior?

Comment: Maybe you want [template template parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213761/what-are-some-uses-of-template-template-parameters)?

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly the solution proposed below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change `foo` to accept a template template parameter `CT` that is templated on two types, and `enable_if` the specific overload based on whether `CT<Res, S>` is the same type as `A<Res, S>`, or `B<Res, S>`:

```
template<typename S, template<typename, typename> typename CT,
    std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<CT<Res,S>, A<Res,S>>::value, bool> = true
>
void foo() 
{
    A<Res, S> a_res;
    A<Jac, S> a_jac;
}

template<typename S, template<typename, typename> typename CT,
    std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<CT<Res, S>, B<Res,S>>::value, bool> = true
>
void foo()
{
    B<Res, S> b_res;
    B<Jac, S> b_jac;
}
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/1d3E1T).