# Pass function template as argument to normal function to be specialised differently within the normal function

Tags: c++

I would like to do something to the following effect:

```
template <class A>
A doThings(A input) { /* do something */ }

void doTwoThings(ClassB inputB, ClassC inputC, template <class A> A(A) func) // This syntax is wrong but how to achieve this effect?
{
  std::cout << func<ClassB>(inputB);
  std::cout << func<ClassC>(inputC);
}

doTwoThings(5, "testStr", doThings);
```

Basically, I am trying to pass a function template as an argument to a normal function, and within that function, specialise the function template into two or more overloads and use them. Is there a way to do that in C++?

Comment: you are looking for template template parameters

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213761/what-are-some-uses-of-template-template-parameters

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number: apply to class, not function.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number can you please give some simple code examples on how it can be used to achieve the outcome I described in my question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if it match your need, but you might do

```
template <typename F>
void doTwoThings(ClassB inputB, ClassC inputC, F func)
{
  std::cout << func(inputB);
  std::cout << func(inputC);
}

doTwoThings(5, "testStr", [](const auto& input){ doThings(input); });
```

Comment: This achieves exactly what I wanted to do. However I wonder if there is a way to do this in C++11? Because auto& for lambda argument is only available from c++14 onwards.

Comment: You can still create an *"old"* functor: `struct ThingDoer { template <typename T> void operator()(const T& input )const { doThings(input); } };` and `oTwoThings(5, "testStr", ThingDoer{});`