# boost::adjacency_list<> and boost::listS

Tags: boost, boost-graph

the [documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/libs/graph/doc/using_adjacency_list.html) says:

> listS selects std::list

The same is being used in an [example](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/libs/graph/doc/using_adjacency_list.html) I'm trying to adapt.

I don't see anywhere in the example where the edge and the vertex type are being passed to boost::adjacency_list<>.
And unsurprisingly constructing the graph using a begin-end pair into a container of edges does not compile for me.

How can one tell the graph library about the type of edges and vertices one intends to use?

Comment: About your confusion, `I'm pretty certain that std::list<> is a template so I'm not following what happens here. `  You can pass a template to a template,  it's called template template parameter. See this so queston for more details. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213761/what-are-some-uses-of-template-template-parameters

Comment: @JohnKoch I know that this is legal and sometimes useful. But this is not my question.

Answer (score 0):

I created a copy of the graph with plain std::size_t for vertices and std::pair<std::size_t, std::size_t> for edges.

I'm unclear why I have to do this, as the graph library is a template library.

Comment: What do you mean, "a copy og the graph"? What did you already have before?

Comment: @sehe I have the graph already stored in some way:

std::map<const node*, std::set<const node*> >

Comment: Then maybe it's better in your case to adapt the graph? I have some answers up on the site already doing as much, but if you need help you could ask a question about that.

Comment: If you post the new question I can post an answer showing e.g. breadth_first_search on that model (PS. if this is at all helpful, please [remember to vote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work))

Answer (score 0):

> **Q.** I don't see anywhere in the example where the edge and the vertex type are being passed to boost::adjacency_list<>.

You choose all the properties of the graph with the template arguments.

The first two choose how edges and vertexes are to be stored. For adjacency-lists, the adjacency-list is a given, but you can choose the edge container selector (which stores the adjacencies (out-edges) *per source vertex*) and the actual vertex container selector (which stores the vertices themselves).

The other template arguments include the vertex/edge and graph properties. So, where the container selectors choose *how* to store graph entities, the properties describe *what* should be stored.

*HOW* everything is being stored is ultimately an implementation detail.

> **Q.** And unsurprisingly constructing the graph using a begin-end pair into a container of edges does not compile for me.

We can't say anything about that, because we don't know what you mean by "a container of edges". Do you already have your graph in some other format?¹

The constructor arguments are not **required** to build a graph. E.g.:

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
using G = boost::adjacency_list<>;

int main() {
    G g(10);
}
```

Is the simplest possible program that creates a graph with 10, unconnected, vertices. To also print it: **[Live](https://godbolt.org/z/xbsTrroPj)**

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/graph_utility.hpp>
using G = boost::adjacency_list<>;

int main() {
    G g(10);
    print_graph(g);
}
```

Output shows 10 vertices with no adjacencies:

```
0 --> 
1 --> 
2 --> 
3 --> 
4 --> 
5 --> 
6 --> 
7 --> 
8 --> 
9 -->
```

> How can one tell the graph library about the type of edges and vertices one intends to use?

Let me start with the "using", then modify the types a little:

Instead you can add edges/vertices after construction: **[Live](https://godbolt.org/z/xh516srso)**

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/graph_utility.hpp>

using G = boost::adjacency_list<>;
using V = G::vertex_descriptor;
using E = G::edge_descriptor;

int main() {
    G g;

    V v1 = add_vertex(g);
    V v2 = add_vertex(g);
    E e1 = add_edge(v1, v2, g).first;
    // or:
    auto [ed, inserted] = add_edge(v1, v2, g);

    std::cout << "Second insertion happened: " << std::boolalpha << inserted << "\n";

    print_graph(g);
}
```

Output:

```
Second insertion happened: true
0 --> 1 1 
1 -->
```

Now, let's immediately show the effect of `setS` as edge storage:

```
using G = boost::adjacency_list<boost::setS>;
```

Output [becomes](https://godbolt.org/z/e17nsfze4) - because the `setS` doesn't admit duplicate out-edges:

```
Second insertion happened: false
0 --> 1 
1 -->
```

Now, let's also try a different vertex container selector?

```
using G = boost::adjacency_list<boost::setS, boost::listS>;
```

Uhoh, now [there is trouble printing the graph](https://godbolt.org/z/j3aa3rzj8), because, as you might have read already in the [linked documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/libs/graph/doc/adjacency_list.html#:%7E:text=If%20the%20VertexList,Readable%20Property%20Map.):

> `If the VertexList of the graph is vecS, then the graph has a builtin vertex indices accessed via the property map for the vertex_index_t property. The indices fall in the range [0, num_vertices(g)) and are contiguous. When a vertex is removed the indices are adjusted so that they retain these properties. Some care must be taken when using these indices to access exterior property storage. The property map for vertex index is a model of Readable Property Map.`

If you use `listS` then there is no implicit vertex index. Of course, we can add an index, but let's instead add a name property to our vertex.

There are **many** ways to [add properties](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/libs/graph/doc/using_adjacency_list.html#:%7E:text=NOTE%3A%20The%20Boost%20Graph%20Library%20supports%20two%20interchangeable%20methods%20for%20specifying%20interior%20properties), but let me show you the more versatile/friendly version: [bundled properties](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/libs/graph/doc/bundles.html):

```
struct VertexProps {
    std::string name;
};

using G = boost::adjacency_list<boost::setS, boost::listS, boost::undirectedS, VertexProps>;
```

Now, all we need to do is tell `print_graph` to use the `name` property from the bundle instead of the vertex index (which isn't usable for printing since `listS`):

```
print_graph(g, get(&VertexProps::name, g));
```

Of course, it becomes nicer when you actually give the vertices names:

```
V v1 = add_vertex(VertexProps{"v1"}, g);
V v2 = add_vertex(VertexProps{"v2"}, g);
```

But of course, names can be changed:

```
g[v2].name += "(changed)";
```

See it all together: **[Live](https://godbolt.org/z/YaMa8Mvcf)**

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/graph_utility.hpp>

struct VertexProps {
    std::string name;
};

using G = boost::adjacency_list<boost::setS, boost::listS, boost::undirectedS, VertexProps>;
using V = G::vertex_descriptor;
using E = G::edge_descriptor;

int main() {
    G g;

    V v1 = add_vertex(VertexProps{"v1"}, g);
    V v2 = add_vertex(VertexProps{"v2"}, g);
    E e1 = add_edge(v1, v2, g).first;
    // or:
    auto [ed, inserted] = add_edge(v1, v2, g);

    g[v2].name += "(changed)";
    std::cout << "Second insertion happened: " << std::boolalpha << inserted << "\n";

    print_graph(g, get(&VertexProps::name, g));
}
```

Prints

```
Second insertion happened: false
v1 <--> v2(changed) 
v2(changed) <--> v1
```

---

¹ *You may not need to copy anything at all, just adapt/use the existing graph)*

Comment: Just a sidenote: the iterator-based constructors may be handy even when it doesn't imply copying the data: [constructing edges directly from a stream](https://godbolt.org/z/Y7n6rYbMn) (although I would recommend adjacency_list_io instead: https://godbolt.org/z/cfdjP5zGd)