# Is there a way to pass a function template into a function?

Tags: c++, templates

I have some template code that takes a function as an argument.  I'd like to extend it to use a function template as an argument.

The existing code is:

```
int add1( int i ) { return i+1; }

template <typename Func, typename Integer>
Integer call_func( Func f, Integer i ) { return f(i); }

// Usage is
auto four = call_func( add1, 3 );
```

It works fine.  If I add a version of add1 that takes a template parameter, I get:

```
template <typename Integer>
Integer add1_t( Integer i ) { return i+1; }

// Usage is
auto four = call_func( add1_t<int>, 3 );
```

What I would really like to do, however, is to not specify the full type of the function, only the template, as in:

```
auto four = call_func( add1_t, 3 );
```

and let call_func apply the template argument.  Is there a way to do that?

My best guess is:

```
template <template <typename> typename Func, typename Integer>
Integer call_func( Func<Integer> f, Integer i ) { return f(i); }
```

but the type of f cannot be deduced when I do that.  Even if I wanted to supply an explicit "type" at the call-site, I'm not sure what that would be.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are some uses of template template parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213761/what-are-some-uses-of-template-template-parameters)

Comment: Afaik this cannot be done exactly this way, but you could easily write code that allows for the exact same syntax: `struct Func { template<class T> constexpr T operator()(T i) const { return i + 1;}}; constexpr Func add1; template<class T, class U> constexpr decltype(auto) call_func(T&& t, U&& u) { return std::forward<T>(t)(std::forward<U>(u)); }; auto four = call_func(add1, 3);`

Comment: @Nelfeal, it doesn't really answer the question directly.  The examples in that article involve template classes, not template functions.  The problem I'm getting is that Func<Integer> is an unresolved overloaded function, which isn't a type.  The other comment is essentially to wrap the function in a struct.  I can certainly go that way - I was just hoping to avoid the syntax of wrapping functions in structs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comment:

> I was just hoping to avoid the syntax of wrapping functions in structs

Making functors (basically wrapping functions in classes) is a pretty common solution to things that involve passing functions around.

Here is one way to do that in your case:

```
template <typename Integer>
struct add1_t {
    Integer operator()( Integer i ) { return i+1; }
};

template <template <typename> class F, typename Integer>
Integer call_func( Integer i ) { return F<Integer>{}(i); }

int main() {
    auto four = call_func<add1_t>( 3 );
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/sY6zas9xf)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass template function.
but you can pass functor with template `operator()`.

Lambda does that job easily, keep your original `call_func`, and change call to:

```
auto four = call_func([](auto arg){ return add1_t(arg)], 3 );
```

MACRO can also help:

```
#define OVERLOAD_SET(FUNC_NAME) [](auto&&... args){ return FUNC_NAME(decltype(args)(args)...); }
// Can be improved with noexcept, and SFINAE friendly

auto four = call_func(OVERLOAD_SET(add1_t), 3 );
```