# How to define and use std::less as a template argument in a function definition?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, functor, function-templates

What is the proper C++ syntax to supply and use `std::less` as a template argument?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

template<typename CMP>
float order(float a, float b)
{
    return CMP(a, b) ? a : b;               // COMPILE ERROR                                                               
    // return CMP::operator()(a,b) ? a : b; //  another try
    // return (a CMP b) ? a : b;            // ¯\_(ツ)_/¯
}

int main() 
{
    const float A = order<std::less<float>>(3.1, 7.2);  // COMPILE ERROR
    const float B = order<std::greater<float>>(3.1, 7.2);
    std::cout << "A=" << A << "\n";
    std::cout << "B=" << B << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

COMPILE ERROR:

```
$ g++ -std=c++17 foo.cpp -o foo

foo.cpp:6:12: error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'std::__1::less<float>'
foo.cpp:12:21: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'order<std::__1::less<float> >' requested here
const float A = order<std::less<float>>(3.1, 7.2);
                ^
```

Comment: Since `CMP` is a type name you have to create an object first, e.g.: `return CMP{}(a,b) ? a : b;`

Comment: Reading the error message *no matching constructor* says the compiler's trying to use `CMP(a,b)` as a constructor rather than invoking the call operator. The answer and above comment explain why.

Comment: A well-designed interface would not prevent the use of a stateful comparison predicate. `template<typename CMP> float order(float a, float b, CMP cmp = {}) { return cmp(a,b) ? a : b;  }`, and it also give a more elegant implementation.

Comment: @alfC Would this still work if `CMP` had only explicit constructors?

Comment: @Amolgorithm, yes. But then you will need to pass a way to construct it. Which is correct.  Anyway, your doubt is, I think, why most people hesitate to use it the idiom.  https://godbolt.org/z/41GrcjnTG

Comment: @Amolgorithm, I misundertood your question. Yes, if the class as an explicit *default* constructor one needs something more verbose: `template<typename CMP>
float order(float a, float b, CMP cmp = CMP{}) ` https://godbolt.org/z/o5vnfT3n8 . But, how writes default constructor that are explicit ?

Comment: If you would like to be able to compare two values of different types (e.g `int` and `float`), without type casting occurring, then I would not recommend using `std::greater` and `std::less`. Instead, it would be a better idea to implement a less function and a greater function separately. Both of these functions would need to be able to support two different types, which could be done with two different parameters for the template.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just return it like this:

```
return CMP{}(a,b) ? a : b;
```

This is because the constructor of `std::less` does not take any parameters.

`CMP` is a type, so you need to create an object of this type first, `CMP{}`, before you can invoke the `()` operator on the temporary `CMP` to do the comparison.

What the above solution does is: It instantiates an `std::less` object and then invokes `operator()` with the parameters `a` and `b`. This operator function then takes the two parameters and returns true if `a` is the lesser one (a boolean expresion). Then, via your ternary check, the smaller value between `a` and `b` is returned.

Comment: Do you think most C++ compilers will optimize the object construction away and just generate a simple comparison instruction?

Comment: @wcochran Not sure. If they are modern C++ compilers, they should be able to. I am only aware that MS Visual Studio will do this. I am not sure about GCC and Clang.

Answer (score 3):

> What is the proper C++ syntax to supply and use `std::less` as a template argument?

The `std::less` or `std::greater` are functors (i.e. function object). This means, prior to the `operator()` call, you need to default constructed them. Therefore, the return statement must be

```
return CMP{}(a,b) ? a : b;
//     ^^^^^^ ----> default construct the function object
```

However, if you want to save some typing, you might use [template-template parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213761/what-are-some-uses-of-template-template-parameters) for the `order`. Optionally, you can provide a template parameter(i.e `typename T`), to make it more generic (If intended)  :

```
template<template<typename> class CMP, typename T>
//       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ --> template-template argument
constexpr auto order(T a, T b) 
{
    return CMP{}(a, b) ? a : b;
}
```

Now you call the `order` as

```
const auto A = order<std::less>(3.1, 7.2); 
//                  ^^^^^^^^^^^ -----> only specify the funnctor
const auto B = order<std::greater>(3.1, 7.2);
//                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ --> only specify the funnctor
```

Comment: Nice, but the nested template sort of scares me.

Comment: I wouldn't do this. Not all comparators are templates, I would be very annoyed if a library I use only accepted templated ones.

Answer (score 2):

A well-designed interface would not prevent the use of a stateful comparison predicate.
And for free, you get a nicer implementation of the other alternatives.

```
template<typename CMP> float order(float a, float b, CMP cmp = {}) {
   return cmp(a, b) ? a : b;
}
```

NOTE 1:

Despite popular belief, if `CMP` is not default constructible, the syntax will still work; but of course, you will need to pass a way to construct it.
Which is good.

test:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

template<typename CMP>
float order(float a, float b, CMP cmp = {}) {
    return cmp(a,b) ? a : b;                                            
}

template<class T>
struct LESS : std::less<T> {
    LESS() = delete;
    LESS(const char*) {}
};

int main() {
    const float A = order<std::less   <float>>(3.1, 7.2);
    const float B = order<std::greater<float>>(3.1, 7.2);
    const float C = order<     LESS   <float>>(3.1, 7.2, "less");
    // const float D = order<     LESS   <float>>(3.1, 7.2);  // compile error, good!

    std::cout << "A=" << A << "\n";
    std::cout << "B=" << B << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

NOTE 2:

A better-designed interface will have a default order:

```
template<typename CMP = std::less<float> >
float order(float a, float b, CMP cmp = {}) {
    return cmp(a,b) ? a : b;                                            
}
```

NOTE 3:

Technically, if the class has an *explicit default constructor*, one needs something more verbose for this to work, but I wouldn't implement this way because, if the default constructor is explicit, there must be a good reason for it, and we are basically overriding the intended behavior of the class designer.

```
template<typename CMP = std::less<float> >
float order(float a, float b, CMP cmp = CMP{}) {  // MMM, good idea?
    return cmp(a,b) ? a : b;                                            
}
```

---

Bonus:

Some people (including STL, https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) do not tolerate default parameters:

```
template<typename CMP>
float order(float a, float b, CMP cmp) {
    return cmp(a,b) ? a : b;                                            
}

template<typename CMP>
float order(float a, float b) {
    return order<CMP>(a, b, {}); // or CMP{});
}

float order(float a, float b) {
    return order<std::less<float>>(a, b);
}
```

Comment: My motivation is to use a C++ templated version of the C macro here: https://github.com/vlfeat/vlfeat/blob/master/vl/covdet.c#L1071  It needs to be as lean and mean as possible (This C macro is very effective on that end).

Comment: I like the bonus example .. I can be more confident the compiler will optimize down to a comparison instruction.

Comment: @wcochran, the reason I like interfaces without template parameters is not efficiency or control. The reason is that, except for trivial cases, IMO interfaces with default parameters tend to be sloppy and scale poorly.

Comment: This is one of those cases where efficiency is a high priority -- I definitely want to do all I can to force the compiler to boil the comparison code to just a processor instruction -- inlining everything.

Comment: @wcochran, I doubt using or not using default arguments will make any difference, but if it lets you sleep better...